# What does this statement return?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a class like this:

```
class Owner
{
private:
    long m_Id;
    QString m_Name;

public:
    Owner() : m_Id(0) { ; }
    virtual ~Owner() { ; }

    inline long id() const { return m_Id; }
    inline void setId(long id) { m_Id = id; }

    inline const QString & name() const { return m_Name; }
    inline void setName(const QString & name) { m_Name = name; }
}
```

I saw a code `&Owner::m_Id;`. I'm confused, does it return a pointer to the member? and if so, how can it be used on Owner's instances?

Comment: Could you provide some context to the usage of the `&Owner::m_Id`?

Comment: In what context have you seen such a thing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++, function pointer to member function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402579/c-function-pointer-to-member-function)

Comment: @MikeDeSimone `m_Id` is not a function, so that's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does return a [*member pointer*](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/cplr034.htm). You can use it to access `m_Id` *indirectly*, as follows:

```
long Owner::* ptrMem = &Owner::m_Id;
Owner owner;
owner.*ptrMem = 10;
cout << owner.m_Id << endl;
```

This code works in a context where `m_Id` is accessible, for example in a member function.

This example is not too interesting, because your class does not have other members of type `long`. In situations where multiple such members exist, member pointers become more valuable: you can postpone the binding to a particular member to run-time.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was what I wanted to hear.Don't understand why so many downvotes :(

Comment: @Davita "Don't understand why so many downvotes" neither do I - I think it's a valid question, so I upvoted it.