# pass an object and one of its methods as an argument

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, parameter-passing, function-pointers

I have a model with a few algorithms and I have to test the algorithms so many times in different ways. It is **very hard** for me to change anything in the class just for the purpose of testing  (in so many files). I want to tell the compiler to run which method on which object. Each time, I have two algorithms to compare and I have over 10 test filers `test1.cpp` ... `test10.cpp` ... . Therefore it is hard to adjust each test files. The name of algorithms is also different in each file. I am looking for a way to pass the methods to the `profiler` from the `main`. In fact adjusting everything only from the main. I only copy/past the algorithms into the model class and then fix the main function without changing the anything inside the class (after copy/pasting the algorithms) or the profile function. The following code shows what I need. Feel free to tweak the structure of this code without breaking the model class into two classes. I must remain only one class.

Please do not send (migrate) this question to code review since it is a draft code (last time I got so many down votes just because of mistake of someone.)

Welcome to the simplest and most readable suggestion.

```
#include <iostream>

class CModel
{
public:
    // ....
    // ....
    // ....

    CModel()
    {
    }

    double algorithm1()
    {
        double result=0;
        // ...
        return result;
    }


    double algorithm2()
    {
        double result=0;
        // ...
        return result;
    }

};

void profiler(CModel &model,double (*algorithm)(void))
{
    // CTimer mytimer;
    // mytimer.start();
    // using model fields here
    double result=model.(*algorithm)();
    // mytimer.stop();
    std::cout<<"out: "<<result<<std::endl;
    // std::cout<<"time elapsed: "<<mytimer.duration;
}

int main()
{
    CModel m1, m2;
    // m1.something= something else;
    // m2.something= something else;
    profiler(m1,m1.algorithm1); // *** impossible ***
    profiler(m2,m2.algorithm2); // *** impossible ***
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to declare the function to take a member function

   ```
   void profiler(CModel &model, double (CModel::*algorithm)())
   ```
2. You need to pass the function a pointer to the member function

   ```
   profiler(m1, &CModel::algorithm1);
   profiler(m2, &CModel::algorithm2);
   ```
3. You need to call the member function correctly

   ```
   double result = (model.*algorithm)();
   ```

---

See [C++, function pointer to member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402579/c-function-pointer-to-member-function) for more details.

Comment: @ar2015 I just noticed and added an edit for that part.

Answer (score 0):

How about changing profiler function in this way?

```
#include <functional>

void profiler(std::function<void()> func) {
    // CTimer mytimer;
    // mytimer.start();
    func();
    // mytimer.stop();
    // std::cout<<"time elapsed: "<<mytimer.duration;   
}
```

Use profiler:

```
CModel m1, m2;
profiler([&m1](){
   double d = m1.algorithm1();
});
profiler([&m2](){
   double d = m2.algorithm2();
});
```

Or just the same object if possible:

```
CModel m1;
profiler([&m1](){
   double d = m1.algorithm1();
});
profiler([&m1](){
   double d = m1.algorithm2();
});
```

Comment: You may even take a template: `template <typename F> void profiler(F f) { /*timer code*/ f(); }` with same calling syntax.

Comment: f() is a void(). A generic F is little meaningful here.