# Call member function on string command

Tags: c++

I have been attempting a sort of text-based command interface for a virtual board game. I've been reading on member functions as parameters, but all my attempts so far have not produced results.
My intent was to be modular so that I can easily add commands by setting a string to call them by in the console.

This is the function I use to call for each function:

```
void command(string in, string name, void (*fnc)())
{
    if(in == name)
    {
        (*fnc)();
    }
}
```

I am calling this in my play() function:

```
void play()
{
    string cmd;
    do
    {
        getline(cin, cmd);
        command(cmd, "print_all", &print_all);
    }
    while(cmd != "exit");
}
```

print_all():

```
void print_all()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << cards[i].name
        << "/n Mana:" << cards[i].cost
        << "/n Attack:" << cards[i].attack
        << "/n Defense:" << cards[i].defense
        << endl;
    }
}
```

Here is the constructor, as to provide more information on the code:

```
public:
game()
{
    init_cards(); // This just fills the vector "cards" with data.
    play();
}
```

And here is my main:

```
int main()
{
    game GAME;
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason, this is producin this error:
`error: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say '&game::print_all' [-fpermissive]|`

I have tried replacing the call parameter with `&game::print_all`, as recommended by the error log, but to no effect.

Thank you for any help in advance. Hopefully, it's a simple fix and I'm just too blind to see it.

Comment: There are not enough information to can give an answer. First of all, this functions looks to be member function(from the error code you've posted). It is this the case?

Comment: All functions are members of my class "game". in main() I only define the object with "game GAME;". All other functions are called in the constructor.

Comment: ok, the issue is simple: I've posted the answer with code example on "duplicate post". I don't think they are duplicated. Your issue is different because everything is happening in member functions.

Comment: It's solves your issue?

Comment: Thank you, sir! You are a scholar and a saint. Do you mind if I ask you why this needs to be done in order to facilitate it as a usable void parameter?

Comment: if you really want to understand, I think this FAQ can explain better than I can in this comment section: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members

Comment: Ah, thank you. I will read through it.