# How to add a constructor with pointer to function as a parameter

Tags: c++

I have this following struct (in the header file):

```
struct StateTransitions {
    State currentState;
    State nextState;
    void (*fn)();

    StateTransitions (State currentState, State nextState, void (*fn)())
    {

    }
};
```

And I am trying to push some instances of this struct into a vector (inside .cpp file):

```
void MyClass::Start()
{

}

transitions.push_back(StateTransitions(Low, Started, &MyClass::Start));
```

I cannot get this to compile. I am not sure if my declaration of the constructor inside the class is correct.

What is the correct way to add a constructor so I can't add this type of objects to my vector ?

I am using pre-C++11.

Comment: Function pointer and member function pointer are different. You might want `void (MyClass::*)()`.

Comment: You should include your compiler error.

Comment: @songyuanyao: you are right, I got confused. This seems to build now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass a pointer to a member function as a static function. The reason is that a member function needs something to be passed to the `this` pointer, while a static function does not (and the compiler needs to check the type of whatever you are passing as this).

See also: [Function pointer to member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402579/function-pointer-to-member-function)