# Passing an object method to a variable

Tags: c++, function-pointers

How to invoke an object method passed to a variable?

```
class A {
public:
    inline int f() {
        return 1;
    }
};


int main() {
    A a;

    int (A::*y)(); //'y' must be a method of 'A' class that returns 'int'
    y = &A::f; //bind 'f' method

    *y(); //how to invoke???
}
```

The other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402579/function-pointer-to-member-function) bound a method to an object field and it was invoked this way `(a.*(a.x))()`, but i can't find a way to do a similar thing to a simple variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do `(a.*y)();`. You need the extra parantheses make the compiler resolve the pointer to member before making the function call. See [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence):

```
class A {
public:
    inline int f() {
        return 1;
    }
};


int main() {
    A a;

    int (A::*y)(); //'y' must be a method of 'A' class that returns 'int'
    y = &A::f; //bind 'f' method

    (a.*y)();
}
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e0b709b696bc045)

Comment: How can I get the name of the function (in this case it will be `f`) that was passed to a variable `y`?

Comment: @Humberd, there's no portable or easy way... The current means is via `std::type_info` which would't give you the name you hope for. We hope some reflection proposals scale through for C++20 ... :-)