# no known conversion 'float (MyClass::*)' to 'float (*)'

Tags: c++

I am supposed to write a program which has to generate a triangle function, calculate the derivative using forward and backward divided differences and differentiate the triangle function.
So, I wrote some code and have only one problem:

> include\MyClass.h|12|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'float (MyClass::*)(int, float, float)' to 'float (*)(int, float, float)'|

My code:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MyClass.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    MyClass object (3,4,2,0.1);

    for (float i=object.x; i<2.5; i+=0.01)
    {
        cout << object.Triangle(10, 3.14, i) << " ";
    }

    cout << "////////////////////";

    for (float i=object.x; i<2.5; i+=0.01)
    {
        cout << object.Derivative(&object.Triangle, i, object.con) << " ";
    }
}
```

MyClass.h

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H


class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass();
        MyClass(int k_max, float omega, float x, float con);
        ~MyClass();
        float Triangle (int k_max, float omega, float x);
        float Derivative (float (*w) (int k_max, float omega, float x), float var, float con);
        float DerivativeCntr (float (*w) (int k_max, float omega, float x), float var, float con);
        int k_max;
        float omega, x, result, con;
};

#endif // MYCLASS_H
```

MyClass.cpp

```
#include "MyClass.h"

MyClass::MyClass() {}
MyClass::~MyClass() {}

MyClass(int K_max, float Omega, float X, float Con)
{
    k_max=K_max;
    omega=Omega;
    x=X;
    con=Con;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////

float Triangle (int k_max, float omega, float x)
    {
        result=0;

        for int (i=0; i<=k_max; i++)
        {
            result += ( 8*pow(-1, i)*(sin((2*i+1)*omega*x ) / ( pow(2*i+1, 2) * pow(M_PI, 2) )
        }
        return result;
    }

///////////////////////////////////////////////

float Derivative (float (*w) (int k_max, float omega, float x), float var, float con)
    {
        float result = (w(10, 3.14, var+con) - w(10, 3.14, var))/var;
        return result;
    }

///////////////////////////////////////////////

float DerivativeCntr (float (*w) (int k_max, float omega, float x), float var, float con)
    {
        float result=(w(10, 3.14, var)-w(10, 3.14, var-con))/2*var;
        return result;
    }
```

I would really appreciate your help, thanks!

EDIT:
I've got this program working, but it's recommended to use a class and required to use a pointer to the function. That's my non object-oriented code:
https://ideone.com/mtPLAo

Comment: Member function pointers are not directly convertible to non-member function pointers.

Comment: You have a mismatch of parentheses in `MyClass.h`

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402579/function-pointer-to-member-function

Comment: @Tobias I am total noob in C++. What should i do?

Comment: Count the parenthesis and make sure the opens and the closes balance. If they don't add the ones that are missing.

Comment: This stuff is non-trivial and requires a lot of answering to get right. Here's a really good document on method pointers and how to use them: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members

Comment: Come to think of it, as a total noob, you shouldn't have to be doing this. The assignment almost certainly wants you to do something else (or the instructor is a nasty <expletive deleted>). Give us a bit more context on the problem and maybe we can help figure out a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors of syntactical nature in your code.

In `MyClass.h`, change into

```
float Derivative (float *w, int k_max, float omega, float x, float var, float con);
float DerivativeCntr (float *w, int k_max, float omega, float x, float var, float con);
```

In `MyClass.cpp`, all member functions should be prefixed by `MyClass::` and also the same for the constructor that takes arguments.

Comment: Now I've got error "candidate expects 6 arguments, 3 provided" in main. Those functions are wrote like this, because they should contain a pointer to "Triangle" function.

Comment: One more mistake being made that should be brought to Askers attention: You can't do this: `&object.Triangle`. Need `&MyClass::Triangle` and to supply the instance later. That or look at `std::bind` and lambdas.

Comment: Two more. Forgot about the one @FrançoisAndrieux mentioned above.