# Syntax to get function pointers in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, pointer-to-member

I am trying to understand function pointers and I have the following test code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test {
public:
    void test_func() {
        cout << "Test func called.";
    }
};

void outer_test_func(Test &t, void (Test::*func)()) {
    (t.*func)();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    auto t = Test();
    outer_test_func(t, &Test::test_func);
}
```

This works. But from what I understand `Test::test_func` and `&Test::test_func` both result in pointers. So why can't I use the former instead of the latter? If I try it g++ complains.

Comment: You are playing around with pointers to **non-static member functions**. They are a different beast.

Comment: In what situation does `Test::test_func` result in a pointer? Without any confirming examples, it's just an assumption.

Comment: As you will recall, member functions are members of an object. Without the "this" parameter, they wouldn't make any sense. Rewrite the example using private: std::string m_testmessage, and print that, and imagine how that would work without the Test &t object to carry the member data.

Comment: _"So why can't I use the former instead of the latter? If I try it g++ complains."_ Didn't you just answer your own question? You can't use it because it's not valid syntax in that context as defined by the language, and that's why the compiler complains.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function pointer to member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402579/function-pointer-to-member-function)

Comment: The name of a free function easily decays to a pointer, because that's how they work in C. Member functions are C++ only and designed differently.

Comment: If you are using C++11, I highly recommend learning how to use std::function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But from what I understand Test::test_func and &Test::test_func both result in pointers.

`Test::test_func` is not a valid syntax for creating pointer to member function, nor pointer to data members. It has never been a valid C++ syntax.

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_data_members) (emphasis mine),

> A pointer to non-static member object m which is a member of class C can be initialized with the expression **&C::m exactly**. Expressions such as &(C::m) or &m inside C's member function do not form pointers to members.