# Function pointer to class member generate compiler error

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers

***Dear reader*** 
I'm making a library module for a process scheduler. Default the scheduler has 8 entries 0..7 and the functions/processes in the scheduler are called using a function pointer. Written as a normal C program it works as expected. But now I want to configure the function pointer in the .h file I have compiler errors pointing at the function pointers. 
I have a problem with the function pointer located at &scheduler::dummy in the proclist[8], they generate me errors and I don't know how to solve them.

> Can some one advice me what to do.

**The error the produce are**

```
scheduler.cpp:9: In file included from

Error compiling libraries

scheduler.h: 56:87: error:
cannot convert 'void (scheduler::*)(uint8_t*) {aka void (scheduler::*)(unsigned char*)}' to 'void (*)(uint8_t*) {aka void (*)(unsigned char*)}' in initialization 
           { 7, 3900  ,10000 ,0,PROC_ACT ,&scheduler*: dummy7 , &proclist[7].val ,65  ,1}}; 
\\process table entry 7
Build failed for project 'Scheduler'
```

and 7x time this error.

```
scheduler.h: 56:87: error: 
 cannot convert 'void (scheduler::*)(uint8_t*) {aka void (scheduler::*)(unsigned char*)}' to 'void (*)(uint8_t*) {aka void (*)(unsigned char*)}' in initialization
```

**The code in the .h file is the following**  
  (line 56 is indicaded in the code block)

```
 //process structure
typedef struct  process_t{                                  // Start of the Process scheduler structure
    uint8_t                         index               ;   // index of this process in the  process structure array
    uint32_t                        starttime           ;   // Absolute start and next call time of the function
    uint32_t                        delta               ;   // Time between the function to be called
    uint32_t                        exetime             ;   // Time it takes to execute the function
    uint8_t                         stat                ;   // skip, delete, change, active
    void                          (*pt2function)(uint8_t*) ;// Pointer to function to be called
    uint8_t                        *valptr              ;   // Pointer to value given as function Parameter
    uint8_t                         val                 ;   // Default value being pointed at
    uint8_t                         nextprocess         ;   // Index to next process in the process structure array
};

class scheduler {

    public:
            void    run();
            void    man  (uint8_t *); 
            void    dummy(uint8_t *);


        //  Processes 0,1..5 arrays of Process structs.
            process_t proclist[8]   =   {{0, ROLLOFFSET ,0     ,0,PROC_ACT ,&scheduler::man     , &proclist[0].val ,INIT    ,1} ,   //Initialise(), Run ones in the process list
                                        { 1, 3000       ,2237  ,0,PROC_ACT ,&scheduler::dummy   , &proclist[1].val ,65      ,2} ,   //process table entry 1
                                        { 2, 3100       ,2718  ,0,PROC_ACT ,&scheduler::dummy   , &proclist[2].val ,66      ,3} ,   //process table entry 2  
                                        { 3, 3200       ,3141  ,0,PROC_ACT ,&scheduler::dummy   , &proclist[3].val ,67      ,4} ,   //process table entry 3 
                                        { 4, 3300       ,2237  ,0,PROC_SKP ,&scheduler::dummy   , &proclist[4].val ,65      ,5} ,   //process table entry 4
                                        { 5, 3400       ,2718  ,0,PROC_SKP ,&scheduler::dummy   , &proclist[5].val ,66      ,6} ,   //process table entry 5
                                        { 6, 3500       ,3141  ,0,PROC_SKP ,&scheduler::dummy   , &proclist[6].val ,67      ,7} ,   //process table entry 6
/*===Line 56 ==>*/                      { 7, 3900       ,10000 ,0,PROC_ACT ,&scheduler::dummy   , &proclist[7].val ,65      ,1}};   //process table entry 7

            // and other functions if needed

    private:
            int8_t   n, cnt;
            uint32_t    mmillis();
};
```

Comment: A pointer to a member function is *not* the same as a pointer to a non-member function. The big difference is that a member function needs an object to be called with, and non-member function doesn't. Read about [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), and [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: The error tells you that you function signature is wrong and what it expects. "(scheduler::)(uint8_t) ". Calling the function afterwards is a different matter to which "some programmer dude" has provided the answer for.

Comment: One option is to make `scheduler::nan` and `scheduler::dummy` static member functions (or global functions). If that is not possible then you have to redesign your code along the lines described in the comments above.

Comment: I tried to fix your formatting. I'm not sure if it looks exactly like your original, but at least the types are visible now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function pointer to member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402579/function-pointer-to-member-function)

Answer (score 2):

The non-static member function have a hidden pointer to an instance of the class, `this`, so [Pointers to Member Functions](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members) need an object and you cannot use them like normal function pointers.

Depending on your design you can eother

1. make the methods static:

   ```
   static void    man  (uint8_t *); 
   static void    dummy(uint8_t *);
   ```

   Maybe you'll have to add one more argument to pass a reference to the `scheduler` or the `process_t` instance.
2. or change `pt2function` to pointers to member function:

   ```
   class scheduler;

   //process structure
   struct  process_t{                            // Start of the Process scheduler structure
       // ...
       void  (scheduler::*pt2function)(uint8_t*) ;// Pointer to function to be called
       // ...
   ```

   And you can later use these *pointer to member functions* from `scheduler` like this:

   ```
   class scheduler {
   // ...
   void run() {    
       (this->*proclist[0].pt2function)(proclist[0].valptr);
   }
   ```

<kbd>[Playground](https://godbolt.org/g/EEFbHc)</kbd>

Comment: I implemented the 2nd solution. It generates one error pointing to how I call the scheduled function/process from the scheduler. In "C" I use the following line : proclist[0].pt2function(proclist[0].valptr); that worked. I now have for this specific line the following error scheduler.cpp: 18:45: error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in '((scheduler*)this)->scheduler::proclist[0].scheduler::process_t::pt2function (...)', e.g. '(... ->* ((scheduler*)this)->scheduler::proclist[0].scheduler::process_t::pt2function) (...). Can you advice again how to call the Function

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the 2nd solution and that works as long as I call methods with in the scheduler class. The scheduler however will call methods from other classes. Below and example were I try to call a method called "wifi_manager::statemachine" which manages a wifi connection and is called every 1 second. This pointer assignment fails because this statemachine method is not part of the schedule class but is part of a wifi_manager class. What do I need to do to have my proclist[8] to contain pointers to various methods in various classes which are called by a method "run" in the schedule class and how do I call these functions/methods.

> Hope someone can help me forward on this

```
/*
    scheduler.ino - tested at 7-2-2018
    Created by Oscar Goos, January 2018
    Test on Platform ESP8266-e12.
    Released into the public domain.
    Program size: 250,264 bytes (used 24% of a 1,044,464 byte maximum) (9.02 secs)
    Minimum Memory Usage: 32716 bytes (40% of a 81920 byte maximum) */

    #include "stdio.h"
    #include "scheduler.h"
    #include "wifi_manager.h"

    scheduler scul;

    void setup()
    {
        Serial.begin(115200, SERIAL_8N1);
        Serial.printf("\n");
        scul.proclist[1].pt2function=&wifi_manager::statemachine; // Assign pointer to proclist[1]
      /* add setup code here */
    }

    void loop()
    {
        scul.run();
      /* add main program code here */
    }
```