# Pointer to function in C++

Tags: c++

```
class Person;
class Command {
 private:
    Person * object;
    //what is this? - a functor?...
    void (Person::*method)();
 public:
    Command(Person *a, void(Person::*m() = 0): object(a),method(m) {}
    void execute() { (object->*method(); }
 };

// defining class Person here
class Person {
 private:
    string name;
    Command cmd;
 public:
    Person(string a, Command c): name(a),cmd(c) {}
    void talk();
    void listen();
};
```

I was wondering what line 6 here means? Is that a way of defining a function or a functor? Also where does this type of function def appear and tends to be used? I found this example Under "Design Patterns" within Object Oriented Programming - this approach type is called Behavioural Command Pattern.

Comment: Pointer to function member : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402579/function-pointer-to-member-function and 3.2 http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer

Comment: great thanks! but why do it? whats the use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pointer to `Person` class member taking no parameters and returning `void`.
Such initialization allows class `Command` referring to custom methods of class `Person`. Imagine class `Person` to be defined like this:

```
class Person
{
public:
    void f1() { std::cout << "Call f1\n"; }
    void f2() { std::cout << "Call f2\n"; }
};
```

Then we can create `Command` objects in this way:

```
Person p;
Command c1(&p, &Person::f1);
Command c2(&p, &Person::f2);
```

Executing these commands calls corresponding methods of given person:

```
c1.execute(); // prints "Call f1"
c2.execute(); // prints "Call f2"
```

Answer (score -1):

This code line `void (Person::*method)();` is a function pointer. `void` means that the function that is pointed won't return any data. `(Person::*method)()` is the definition of the pointer, the pointer will point to a `void` function.

In this [page](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html) you can see how the syntax is:

> ### Function Pointer Syntax
>
> The syntax for declaring a function pointer
>   might seem messy at first, but in most cases it's really quite
>   straight-forward once you understand what's going on. Let's look at a
>   simple example:
>
> ```
> void (*foo)(int);
> ```
>
> In this example, foo is a pointer to a function taking one argument,
>   an integer, and that returns void. It's as if you're declaring a
>   function called "*foo", which takes an int and returns void; now, if
>   *foo is a function, then foo must be a pointer to a function. (Similarly, a declaration like int *x can be read as *x is an int, so
>   x must be a pointer to an int.)
>
> The key to writing the declaration for a function pointer is that
>   you're just writing out the declaration of a function but with
>   (*func_name) where you'd normally just put func_name.

Comment: great thanks most useful!

Comment: This is incorrect answer. This is not a "normal" function pointer. Please see other answer.