# Assign to a variable a function from a specific instance of a class to keep the state

Tags: c++

Is it possible to assign a function from a specific instance of a class as a parameter? Multiple classes can have the same signature. Here an example. Thank you!

**UPDATE**: The context is that we are using a third party library that supply us with call back after a device finish the process. The typedef is what look like the signature from the third party library.

**UPDATE**: After checking the link, the solution seems to embed a specific class. Is there a way to be more generic?

```
typedef double(*Processor) (
    double  first,
    double  second
);

double Adjustment = 0.5;
double Multiply(double first, double second)
{
    return first * second * Adjustment;
}

class Substract
{
public:
    double Adjustment;

    Substract(double adjustment) : Adjustment(adjustment) {}

    double Process(double first, double second)
    {
        return first - second - Adjustment;
    }
};

class Add
{
public:
    double Adjustment;

    Add(double adjustment) : Adjustment(adjustment) {}

    double Process(double first, double second)
    {
        return first + second + Adjustment;
    }
};

void Process(Processor processor)
{
    double result = processor(100, 50);
    std::cout << "Multiply=" << result << std::endl;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    double result;

    Process(Multiply); // <-- success

    Substract* substract = new Substract(0.5);
    Process(substract->Process); // <-- not compiling
    delete substract;

    Add* add = new Add(0.5);
    Process(add->Process); // <-- not compiling
    delete add;

    getchar();

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function pointer to member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402579/function-pointer-to-member-function)

Comment: Is there a way to hide my question temporary to check the link? Then I will close it if it works or I will rephrase my question? Thanks

Comment: @SebastienDErrico: The poster can delete its own question and then undelete it - of course you cannot if it was deleted not by you but by the community or a moderator.

Comment: "After checking the link, the solution seems to embed a specific class. Is there a way to be more generic?" If you want generic function, you can always use template.

Comment: @herambled If our third party supplier used typedef double(*Processor), something that we cannot change, is that means we cannot specified a function from an instance, we are stuck using a global function?

Comment: Well, at least not elegantly. member functions must be provided `this` pointer, and `Processor` typedef in your code does not have it. So, if you really want that, you could assign your class instances to global variable, and write a free function that comports to `Processor` signiture that invokes member functions using the global variables. Having said that, it is EXTREMELY dirty.

Comment: @herambled this is EXACTLY what I am trying to refactor. I was trying to remove all global elements creating dependencies to others global elements. Because we are not in position to modify the Processor typedef, I conclude that we are stuck to leave the implementation as is.

Comment: @herambled Thank you for your time. Do you want to turn your comment to an answer? I will click it as best answer. Thanks!

Comment: Sure :) I'll post it with some example code in case that some  other people might need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no elegant way. Member functions must be provided with `this` pointer, and `Processor` typedef in your code does not have it. Even if it has some kind of `void*` that can store your instance pointer, the calling convention of free function and member functions are different. It need to use something like `std::invoke` to properly handle it, which is unlikely for your case.

So, if you really want that, you could assign your class instances to global variable, and write a free function that comports to `Processor` signiture that invokes member functions using the global variables. Having said that, it is **EXTREMELY** dirty.

For example, you can do this:

```
typedef double(*Processor) (
    double  first,
    double  second
);

void Process(Processor processor)
{
    double result = processor(100, 50);
    std::cout << "Multiply=" << result << std::endl;
}

class Add
{
public:
    double Adjustment;

    Add(double adjustment) : Adjustment(adjustment) {}

    double Process(double first, double second)
    {
        return first + second + Adjustment;
    }
};

Add* g_add;

double add_f(double first, double second)
{
    return g_add->Process(first, second);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    g_add = new Add(0.5);
    Process(add_f);
    delete g_add; g_add = nullptr;

    getchar();
}
```

But it leads to **VERY BAD** software design. Replace your third party library to one that supports C++ functors if possible. If not, use this technique only if you are unquestionably sure that you can manage this horrible design.

Comment: Hahaha, thank you for the last paragraph. Unfortunately, our company is integrating a device and the official lib bundled with it force us to use callback with a typedef and I conclude from your answer that the typedef force us to use global instances.

Comment: @sebastien Bad things happen :(