# How to pass an implemented virtual member function as a parameter

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, virtual

```
#include <iostream>

class virtualClass{
public:
    virtual int a() = 0;
};

class UnknownImplementation : public virtualClass{
public:
    int a() override { return 1;}
};

class myFramework {
public:
    int c(int (virtualClass::*implementedFunc)(void)){
        implementedFunc();
        return 2;
    }
};

int main(){
    //some user implements the virtual class and calls myFramework function
    myFramework* mfp = new myFramework();
    std::cout << mfp->c(&(UnknownImplementation::a)) << std::endl;
}
```

Hi, I am working on a framework that is supposed call an implemented virtual function and use it. It is similar to the code above.
The compiling errors I get are:

> > testVirtual.cpp: In member function ‘int myFramework::c(int (virtualClass::*)())’: testVirtual.cpp:16:19: error: must use ‘.*’ or
> >     ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in ‘implementedFunc (...)’,
> >     e.g. ‘(... ->* implementedFunc) (...)’    implementedFunc();
> >                        ^ testVirtual.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: testVirtual.cpp:24:47: error: invalid use of non-static member
> >     function ‘virtual int UnknownImplementation::a()’   std::cout <<
> >     mfp->c(&(UnknownImplementation::a)) << std::endl;

How do I fix these problems?
Thanks in advance!

passing an instance of the implemented class and calling the function worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function pointer to member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402579/function-pointer-to-member-function)

Comment: Better to pass the object of `UnknownImplementation` and call appropriate function of `virtualClass` inside `myFramework::c`. Since every implementation of `virtualClass` would define the functions which could be called from within `myFramework::c`.   This is called command pattern.

Comment: yeah that worked, thanks

Answer (score 1):

To build on sameerkn's comment, this code should be:

```
#include <iostream>

class virtualClass{
public:
    virtual int a() = 0;
};

class mySubclass : public virtualClass{
public:
    int a() override { return 1;}
};

int main(){
    mySubclass * x= new mySubclass ();

    // ...

    std::cout << x->a () << std::endl;
}
```

The point here is that you can pass objects (or pointers) of type `virtualClass` around - even though they might actually be `mySubclass` objects in real life - and still wind up in the right implementation of `a()`.  `myFramework` is entirely unnecessary.

That's what `virtual` methods are for - consumers of `virtualClass` don't need to know anything about classes that might - now or in the future - be derived from it, and if I have read your question correctly, this is what you want.