# How to pass member function as a parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

The C++ syntax is killing me.
I'm trying to pass `this` + pointer to member function:
So I did the following :

```
template <void(Myclass::*func)()>
static void Myfunction(Myclass* theThis)
{
    theThis->*func();
}
```

This works great.

But now I want to pass from this function to another function this member function.

```
template <void(Myclass::*func)()>
static void Myfunction2(Myclass* theThis) // My new function
{
    theThis->*func();
}

template <void(Myclass::*func)()>
static void Myfunction(Myclass* theThis)
{
    Myfunction2<&(Myclass::*func)>(theThis)  // This doesn't compile, the template parameter is probably incorrect
}
```

But it doesn't compile, I'm not sure how to pass this member function.

I get : `error C2059: syntax error: '<tag>::*'`

EDIT:

Just to make things clear.
I don't have a function named func, this is just the name of the pointer to the member function

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2402579/9593596

Comment: `theThis->*func();` is wrong as well, it should be `(theThis->*func)();`.

Comment: @Quentin you're right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`func` is already the value you want to pass, so just pass it:

```
template <void(Myclass::*func)()>
static void Myfunction2(Myclass* theThis) // My new function
{
    (theThis->*func)();
}

template <void(Myclass::*func)()>
static void Myfunction(Myclass* theThis)
{
    Myfunction2<func>(theThis);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you don't use pointer-to-member functions as the template argument at all. Instead use a much simpler type and pass a callable object of that type as the argument.

This will allow you to use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) to bind to functions, or to use [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), or even normal non-member functions.

Perhaps something like this:

```
template<typename C>
void MyFunction2(C callable)
{
    callable();
}

template<typename C>
void MyFunction1(C callable)
{
    MyFunction2(callable);
}
```

To be used either like

```
MyFunction1(std::bind(&MyClass::TheRealFunction, theThis));
```

or

```
MyFunction1([&theThis]()
{
    theThis->TheRealFunction();
});
```

Using templates like that is the common way for all standard library functions taking callable objects as arguments.

---

You can of course use [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), and then not use templates at all:

```
void MyFunction2(std::function<void()> callable)
{
    callable();
}

void MyFunction1(std::function<void()> callable)
{
    MyFunction2(callable);
}
```

Usage is as above.