# How to pass a member function to another function?

Tags: c++

I have a function

```
float addXPercent (float percent, ExampleClass* A, ExampleClass B, thisFunction) {
  return (percent * B.thisFunction() + (*A).thisFunction());
}
```

and `someFunction` is a function that can be applied to both `A` and `B` like this

```
(*A).setSomething(0.4 * B.someFunction() + (*A).someFunction());
```

It takes a `percent` value like `0.4`, applies it to the result of `B.someFunction()` and adds that value to the current value of `A.someFunction()`.

What I want to do is generalize this part of the function out:

```
0.4 * B.someFunction() + (*A).someFunction()
```

into that `addXPercent` function. The result I expect to look something like this

```
(*A).setSomething( addXPercent (0.3, *A, B, thisFunction) );
```

I'm quite new to C++ so I did some googling and found out you can pass function to different function with the std header `<functional>`.

But I'm not sure how I'll pass a member function with syntax like this `function< void () > thisFunction`.

How should I go about doing that?

I wasn't able to find a related thread 1 2 (got `Sorry, there were no post results for “”`) so sorry if this is a duplicate question.

Comment: Please don't split up your code into a bunch of one liners.   Put it all together in something that would compile except for the part specific to your question and then cobble together a line showing what you'd like to do.

Comment: (Off-topic) Use `A->someFunction()` instead of `(*A).someFunction()`. The `->` operator  was invented just for that purpose :-)

Comment: @NikosC. somewhat funnily, he'll probably need to use both at the same time soon.. `->*`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51245152/how-to-pass-member-function-as-a-parameter

Comment: You might be looking for `std::mem_fn`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to do is generalize this part of the function out

You can do this with *[pointer to member function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions)*:

```
float addXPercent (float percent, ExampleClass* A, ExampleClass B, float (ExampleClass::*someFunction)()) {
  return (percent * (B.*someFunction)() + (A->*someFunction)());
}
```

You can call `addXPercent` like this:

```
ExampleClass a, b;

addXPercent(0.3f, &a, b, &ExampleClass::thisFunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your intentions. As far as I know passing functions as parameters can be archived with function pointers, Functors or Lambdas in c++11. For example bellow there's some approach using functors that maybe you'll find useful.

```
class ExampleClass 
{
    float something;

    public:

    void setSomething(float val)
    {
        something = val;
    }

    struct ThisFunction 
    {
      float operator()(ExampleClass &example) {
        // Do whatever you need here
        float result = 2.0;
        return result;
      }
    };

};



float addXPercent (float percent, ExampleClass *A, ExampleClass B, ExampleClass::ThisFunction &thisFunction) {
  return ((percent * thisFunction(B)) + thisFunction((*A)));
}

int main() 
{
    ExampleClass A;
    ExampleClass B;

    ExampleClass::ThisFunction thisFunction;

    A.setSomething(addXPercent (0.3, &A, B, thisFunction));
};
```