# Passing a function declared in class as arguments causes compilation error

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I am facing problems with passing function pointer as arguments.

The declaration of pointer to function type :

```
typedef void(*cbk_fct)(void);
```

The class `Operation` has a constructor that accept a `cbk_fct` as argument the declaration is as follows:

```
class Operation
{
 private:
 cbk_fct m_fct_ptr;

public:
 Operation(cbk_fct fct_ptr);
};

Operation::Operation(cbk_fct fct_ptr):
m_fct_ptr(fct_ptr)
{

}
```

Now the class `User` will call the Constructor of `Operation`

```
class User
{
 public:
 User();
 void userOperation();
};

void User::userOperation()
{
 cout << "User operation"<<endl;
}

User::User()
{
 Operation op(userOperation); // This version doesnt work
}
```

This call will give following error:

```
no matching function for call to 'Operation::Operation(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'|
no known conversion for argument 1 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'cbk_fct {aka void (*)()}'
```

However if I declared the function to be passed as parameter outside the class it will be accepted

```
void UserOperationNotInClass()
{
 cout << "User operation"<<endl;
}

User::User()
{
 Operation op(UserOperationNotInClass); // This version works
}
```

Clearly the error message mention that it is not able to convert from '' to 'cbk_fct, but from where comes this type 'unresolved overloaded function type'

Comment: `userOperation` is a member function pointer, not a `void(*)(void)`. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402579/function-pointer-to-member-function.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @r3musn0x it's a GNU GCC compiler C++98

Comment: @WernerHenze, yes Ok, but in this case my class Operation wont be generic, actually my Idea was that the class Operation just execute the user operation in a certain logic and it is up to the user to choose the operation to be executed, not cool for me :/

Comment: Are you limited to c++98?

Comment: I also tried with c++11 it will also give the same error

Answer (score 1):

A non static member function is **not** the same thing as a normal function. Specifically, it can access its object `this` pointer which would not make sense for a *normal* function. So the compiler is correct when saying that there is no know conversion from the former to the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike free functions, there isn't an implicit conversion from a member function to pointer to member function, so you can never supply `userOperation`. You have to use `&User::userOperation`. The error message could be better in that regard.

Having fixed that, `&User::userOperation` has the type `void (User::*)(void)`, which is not the same as `void (*)(void)` (your alias `cbk_fct`). You always need a `User` to call `userOperation`, and there is nowhere for that. You will have to change `Operation` if you want it to include member functions.

The (C compatible) C++98 way would be to include a `void *` in both the function type, and the members of `Operation`, and pass `this` (or any other object pointer), implicitly converting to `void *`.

```
typedef void * context_ptr;
typedef void (* action_ptr)(context_ptr);

class Operation
{
 private:
 action_ptr m_action;
 context_ptr m_context;

public:
 Operation(action_ptr action, context_ptr context);
};

Operation::Operation(action_ptr action, context_ptr context):
m_action(action), m_context(context)
{}

class User
{
 static void callUserOperation(context_ptr);
 public:
 User();
 void userOperation();
};

void User::callUserOperation(context_ptr context)
{
    User * user = reinterpret_cast<User *>(context);
    user->userOperation();
}

void User::userOperation()
{
 cout << "User operation"<<endl;
}

User::User()
{
 Operation op(&User::callUserOperation, this);
}
```

In C++11, you can use `std::function` to hold any function object of a particular signature, and construct it from a lambda capturing `this` and calling `userOperation`

```
using action_ptr = std::function<void(void)>;

class Operation
{
 private:
 action_ptr m_action;

public:
 Operation(action_ptr action);
};

Operation::Operation(action_ptr action):
m_action(action)
{}

class User
{
 public:
 User();
 void userOperation();
};

void User::userOperation()
{
 cout << "User operation"<<endl;
}

User::User()
{
 Operation op([this]{ userOperation(); });
}
```

Comment: It seems you missed the `User::` in the definition of `callUserOperationIt` apart of this it seems fine I will try it and update the status

Comment: One question in the 1st example the `reinterpret_cast` is not dangerous in this case ?

Comment: No, because *you know* that `callUserOperation` is always associated with a `User *` that has been converted to `void *`. You've just declined to inform the complier directly