# Callback with std::function and arguments

Tags: c++, function, std, std-function

I try to do a router :
`router.get("/mypath", callback)`

But I have some issue with `std::function<void(http::request_parser<http::empty_body>)>` is from boost beast

```
struct Routes {
  typedef  std::function<void(http::request_parser<http::empty_body>)> handler;
};

void get(const std::string& ressource, Routes::handler handler);

router.get("/status", &api::test);

void api::test(http::request_parser<http::empty_body>)
{
    std::cout<<"hello"<<std::endl;
}
```

But I can not call void function, I don't know why

Comment: use `boost::bind` https://cs.brown.edu/~jwicks/boost/libs/bind/bind.html#with_function_objects

Comment: And is `api::test` a static function of the `api` class? Or free function in a method? What's the error message?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402579/function-pointer-to-member-function

Comment: Test is from api class. The error message is `no viable conversion from                 'void (api::*)()' to 'Routes::handler' (aka
      'function<void (boost::beast::http::parser<true,              boost::beast::http::empty_body,
      std::__ndk1::allocator<char> >)>')
        router.get("/status", &api::test);`

Answer (score -1):

`api::test` has 2 params, `handler` function only one.

You need to "adapt" ypur function by [binding](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html) a param

Comment: OP can probably use std::bind here, or even better, lambdas. It's also not the problem at all, the callback is `api::test`, not `get`.

Comment: I prefer use lambda

Comment: But I don't understand why I must use bind or lambda. `get` take 2 parameters, but the handler 1, the callback take 1, and I need only 1 into callback