# Function access using macros

Tags: c++, macros

This problem is caused when I want to get the address of Functions in Macros after the sign(`::`).It always has a trailing whitespace which reports an error.

I'm using G++ in Mac OS Mojave i386.

For example, I have the class:

```cpp
struct A{
  void b();
};
```

and there's a macro:

```cpp
#define ACC(name) &A::name
```

I use this to get the pointer of `A::b`:

```cpp
void(*accab)() = ACC(b);
```

And I will get the error like this:

```
error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'void (*)()' with an rvalue of type 'void (A::*)()'
```

After that I tried putting a bracket but I got this:

```
error: call to non-static member function without an object argument
```

Is there any way to solve the problem so that the pointer can be gotten by macro?

Comment: you have to show how you are using the macro. The macro alone does not produce an error only its expansion, right?

Comment: Somewhere you have code with a `void (*)()` signature.  Such a function pointer cannot hold a `void (A::*)()`.  The types do not match.

Comment: seems to be fine here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/8VhJL5JPo68tEa1T (after making the member public and adding the missing `;`)

Comment: The macro isn't the actual problem. This won't work because a pointer to free function and pointer to member function are different types (you have to provide the `A` object to call `A::b`). See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402579/function-pointer-to-member-function

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with using a macro.  A pointer to a function is a different thing from a pointer to a non-static member function of a class.   The error message you describe suggests you are trying to assign one equal to the other, such is simply not allowed.

Comment: @aschepler yes -facepalm- sorry for that ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of a pointer to function is different from the type of pointer to member function.

In general, the type of pointer to any member is distinct from the type of a normal pointer.

To make this work you will have declare `accab` as pointer to member:

```
void(A::* accab)() = ACC(b);
```

The C++ standard has a [note](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.mptr#3) concerning this:

> The type “pointer to member” is distinct from the type “pointer”, that is, a pointer to member is declared only by the pointer to member declarator syntax, and never by the pointer declarator syntax.