# set value of a pointer into a class member function

Tags: c++, c++11

I got confused while passing pointer of a class member function to a variable.
this is the body of my class:

```
class pjsuaMyClass
{
...
private:
 pj_bool_t default_mod_on_rx_request(pjsip_rx_data *rdata);
....
};
```

in my application there is a structure which gets the pointer of default_mod_on_rx_request to handle the incoming messages. this structure will pass to a initiator function and may call the "on_rx_response" function.

my structure definition:

```
struct pjsip_module mod_default_handler
{
...
pj_bool_t (*on_rx_response)(pjsip_rx_data *rdata);
...
};
```

I set the value of "on_rx_response" into this:

```
mod_default_handler.on_rx_response = &pjsuaMyClass::default_mod_on_rx_request;
```

but I got following error:

```
pjsuamyclass.cpp:24:35: error: assigning to 'pj_bool_t (*)(pjsip_rx_data *)' (aka 'int (*)(pjsip_rx_data *)') from incompatible type 'pj_bool_t (pjsuaMyClass::*)(pjsip_rx_data *)'
```

what should I do to pass this function as my handler?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function pointer to member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402579/function-pointer-to-member-function)

Comment: @AlanBirtles thank you for helping, I tried it already but it did not worked, either I could not understand the sample or there is another problem.

Comment: Please show a [mre] of what you tried

Comment: default_mod_rx_request is a function but you're not giving it any input. So you are assigning a data member to a function

Comment: When someone does `mod_default_handler.on_rx_response(&something);` which instance of `pjsuaMyClass` should it call the function on?

Comment: Just try defining, if not tried already yet, you on_rx_response object like `pj_bool_t (pjsuaMyClass::*on_rx_response)(pjsip_rx_data *rdata);` cc @Arta