# Pointer to function from another pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, arduino, function-pointers, arduino-c++

I'm new to c++ and I'm trying to make a generic switch (i.e. the device, not the C++ statement) that could be used to blink lights, turn beeps on and off, etc, in my Arduino project.

I could create a switchable interface and implement that in the classes that I want to "switch".  But since I'm doing it as study purposes and I saw the pointer-to-functions ability in C++ (that is new to me since I come from C# and Java), I tough it would be a good opportunity to give it a try...

The problem is that I can pass the function in my code only if it's a local function but it won't work if I try to pass a function from another object like a led for example.

Some code to illustrate the problem. This is the `switch.cpp`, it recieves the `On` and `Off` functions in it's constructor and it has a update method that is called inside the loop method in the Arduino ino main class:

```
auto_switch.cpp

using switch_function = void(*)();
auto_switch::auto_switch(const switch_function on_function, const switch_function off_function, const int max_speed_count)
{
    //sets all variables...
}

void auto_switch::update(const unsigned long millis)
{
    //turn switch on and off...
}
```

And this is my ino file

```
ino file

#include <Arduino.h>
#include "led.h"
#include "auto_switch.h"

led* main_led;
auto_switch* led_switch;
int slow_speed;

//ugly code
void turn_led_on()
{
    main_led->turn_on();
}

//ugly code
void turn_led_off()
{
    main_led->turn_off();
}

void setup() {
    main_led = new led(2, 3, 4, true, color::white);

    //ugly code
    led_switch = new auto_switch(turn_led_on, turn_led_off, 3);

    slow_speed = led_switch->add_speed(100, 100, 3, 1000);
    led_switch->set_active_speed(slow_speed);
    led_switch->turn_on();
}

void loop() {
    led_switch->update(millis());
}
```

It works but I had to make a local function (`turn_led_on` and `turn_led_off`) to be able to assign the inner functions as a parameter to the `auto_switch` constructor, the parts that I've wrote `//ugly code`

I wanted to do something like this, without the glue code in between:

```
//doesn't work
led_switch = new auto_switch(main_led->turn_on, main_led->turn_off, 3);
```

Is it possible? I've read something about static pointer to function and some std functions that help with that, if I get it right the glue code is necessary in this case so that the compiler can know where the functions are coming from I guess (from which object), but since the functions I need to call cannot be static I've discarded this option, and the std functions I believe it can't be used with the Arduino or could but shouldn't for performance limitations...

Anyway, does it make sense, can it be done using pointer to functions or should I create a interface or something different?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function pointer to member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402579/function-pointer-to-member-function)

Comment: @Scheff thanks for the suggestion, I've read about member functions but I believe it wouldn't make the switch generic right? I mean, the switch would only work with the member type so I would need one switch classe for every switch target like led, beeps etc right?

Comment: If you write "switch" you don't mean the statement `switch`, don't you? Sorry, that's a bit confusing. However, if you are looking for something more generic which can hold pointers to plain functions as well as member function pointers (with object) I suggest to have a look into [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Comment: if that's right it would be better to use an interface instead I guess?!

Comment: sorry, yes, when I say switch I'm talking about a class called switch that has the ability to call on and off on the target to control lights and so on,,, not the switch case statement....

Comment: @Scheff, about the std::function, I don't know if it's possible to use it with the Arduino, maybe I'm wrong but it seems that it's too heavy for a arduino nano for exemple,,, but I'll look into it...

Comment: just reading more about it std::function uses dynamic memory allocation that is really heavy or impractical for arduino hardware limitations...

Comment: @JheysonBicudodeLima I've written code for Arduino which uses dynamic memory allocation. I don't have an Arduino myself, but the user of the code didn't report any problems. Although `std::function` has some overhead compared to raw member function pointers, it's supposed to be lightweight and I doubt you'll have any problems with it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo it's good to know that, I'll give it a try then, thanks for the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before deciding how to do it, the qquestion is what do you want to do and why.  Because, maybe there are better alternatives using simple C++ idioms.

### Option 1: specialization with polymorphism

Do you want to specialize some functions of your switch, so instead of calling the function of the `auto_switch` you'd call dome more specialized ones ?

In this case you wouldn't do:

```
//doesn't work
led_switch = new auto_switch(main_led->turn_on, main_led->turn_off, 3);
```

but instead you would rely on polymorphism with virtual functions in the base class:

```
class auto_switch {
...
    virtual void turn_on();  
    virtual void turn_off(); 
...
};
```

and write a specialized class for the leds:

```
class led_witch : public auto_switch {
...
    void turn_on() override;  
    void turn_off() override; 
...
};
```

In fact, the compiler will generate some function pointers behind the scene, but you don't have to care:

```
auto_switch s1=new auto_switch(...); 
auto_switch s2=new led_switch(...);   // no problem !! 

s1->turn_on();     // calls auto_switch::turn_on() 
s2->turn_on();     // calls led_switch::turn_on() since the real type of s2 is led_switch
```

But event if each object's behavior is dynamic on the the base of the real class of the object,  the objects of the same class share a behavior that was predefined at compile time. If this is not ok, go to the next option.

### Option 2: the member function pointer

The functions of another objects can only be invoked with that object at hand. So having a function pointer to a led function is not sufficient: you also need to know on which led it shall be applied.

This is why member function pointers are different and somewhat constraint:  you can only invoke functions of class of your member function pointer.  If polymorphism is sufficient (i.e. if derived class has a different implementation of a function already foreseen in the base classe) then you are lucky.   If you want to use a function that only exists in the derived class and not in the base class, it won't compile.

Here a simplified version of `auto_swith`:  I provide a function, but allso a pointer to the object on which the function has to be invoked:

```
class auto_switch{
    void (led::*action)(); 
    led *ld; 
public: 
    auto_switch(void(led::*a)(), led*l) : action(a), ld(l) {}
    void go () { (ld->*action)(); }
}; 
// usage:  
auto_switch s(&led::turn_off, &l1);
s.go();
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/BFpBWh)

### Option 3 : the functional way (may that's what you're looking for ?)

Another variant would be to use the standard functional library to bind a member function and the object on which it shall be executed (as well as any need parameters):

```
class auto_switch{
    std::function<void()> action; 
public: 
    auto_switch(function<void()>a) : action(a) {}
    void go () { action(); }
};
```

Here you can bind anything: any function of any class:

```
auto_switch s(bind(&led::turn_off, l1));
s.go(); 
auto_switch s2(bind(&blinking_led::blink, l2));
s2.go();
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/Kz5LqC)

### Option 4 : command pattern

Now if you want to perform something on an object when you turn on and off the switch, but you need total flexibility,  you can just implement the **[command pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/command-pattern.html)** :  this lets you execute anything on any object.  And you don't even need a function pointer.

Comment: Wow, first thanks for taking your time, it's a really detailed answer... I'll try to comment about the options you told me about:

1:In this case we'd be specializing the auto_switch, my ideia wasn't in heavily specialization but one generic switch with only one behavior that could switch multiple objects... basically the command pattern behavior (that I ended up doing anyway)

2:If I understand it right, doing it this way the auto_switch class gets heavily coupled with the led class, sure in some cases that's completely valid but in my case I wanted I generic switch...

Comment: 3: I believe that the functional way would lead me to the result too but since I've read that I should avoid dynamic memory allocation on arduino it made me avoid that route, but I'll try it too for learning purposes.
4: Exactly the behavior I wanted... but since I'm learning cpp I thought "pointers, why not?"

I ended up doing it using the pattern but since I'm studying cpp for the first time I wanted to make something different using the pointers way to learn how it works and I got stuck and was trying to make it work, but now I don't think its the best way to it...

Comment: summarizing... I was trying to avoid the command pattern way to try to learn something new with function pointer (since the languages I'm used to doesn't have this option) and I though that I could achieve the same result without forcing other classes to implement my command interface by simply using pointer to functions, it would be a win win...
If I got it right, the way to achieve that would be with option 3 and the simpler way would be option 4 with some coupling to my command interface...

thansk again for your help @Christophe