# calling a member function pointer from outside the class - is it possible?

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

suppose I have a class with a member function pointer declared:

```
bool (myclass::*secspec_goutmsg)(char* msg , int n) ;
```

I can declare a method somewhere that simply calls this function pointer and returns the result

```
bool custom_gui(char* msg , int n)
{
    if (secspec_goutmsg !=NULL)
        return (*this.*secspec_goutmsg)(msg , n) ;
    else
        return false ;
}
```

Is it however possible to call this function pointer directly from outside the class eliminating this method that is essentially a wrapper ?
things like

```
(*myclassinstance.*(myclass::secspec_goutmsg))(msg , n) ;
```

do not even compile.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function pointer to member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402579/function-pointer-to-member-function)

Comment: If `myclassinstance` is not a pointer then of course it would not as `this` is a pointer. So you just need to remove *

Comment: this is a pointer, I was thinking that the dereference is to the function pointer, but clearly I'm rather muddled on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you're looking for:

```
(myclassinstance.*myclassinstance.secspec_goutmsg)(msg, n);
```

or from the comments, if myclassinstance is a pointer

```
(myclassinstance->*myclassinstance->secspec_goutmsg)(msg, n);
```

Comment: this doesn't compile. error: request for member 'secspec_goutmsg' in xxxx  which is of pointer type 'myclass* const' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)

Comment: "maybe you meant to use '->'" no we meant to ask for [mcve]

Comment: @camelccc if `myclassinstance` is not actually an instance but a pointer, you do need to replace the operators with `->*` and `->` accordingly.

Comment: thanks that actually compiles doing that. Why does this need the use of myclassinstance twice ?

Comment: @camelccc because you're calling the member function pointer stored *in* this instance, *on* this instance. You could very well use two separate instances, or a MFP from anywhere else.