# C++ Function Callback using class member and run it in main

Tags: c++, function, class, arduino, callback

I know, many post asking about this, been reading about 10 post with long answers but, every post seems different case and needs different implementation.

so, what did i do wrong here?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Foo {
   public:
    void callbackFunc(void (*funcParam1)());
    void funcA();

};
void Foo::callbackFunc(void (*funcParam1)()) {
    funcParam1();
}
void Foo::funcA() { cout << "func A OK.." << endl; }
void aa(){
    int x =0;
}
Foo bar;
int main() { bar.callbackFunc(bar.funcA); }
```

this example throws `error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘void Foo::funcA()’` in the `main()` especially in the `callbackFunc`parameter.

i want to use it in arduino later.

Comment: you need an object to call a member function

Comment: Member function pointers are different from regular function pointers (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402579/function-pointer-to-member-function)

Comment: it is not completely clear what you want to achieve with that design, as `callbackFunc` immediately calls the function. Do you acutally want to store the callback to call it later? Is the signature always `void(*)()`?

Comment: `&Foo::funcA` not `bar.funcA`.

Comment: @idclev463035818 `&Foo::funcA` is the correct syntax to refer to a non-static member function.

Comment: @0x499602D2 sorry, my bad, got confused...

Comment: @idclev463035818 so, it'll be `bar.callbackFunc(&Foo::funcA);` ?

Answer (score 2):

You may get away with the error with `static funcA`:

```
static void funcA();
```

Looks like the problem is that your `callbackFunc` expects a function pointer, but member function `funcA` is not a normal function and expects an object to begin with. Making it `static` would get away of the issue.

Comment: hi, this partially correct. but, later on, each instance will utilize variables from each class. So, making it static won't solve the problem. But, thank you for the answer.