# Pointer to a class method call

Tags: c++, class, pointers, methods, call

I am trying to define a class named `RationalNumber`. In the constructor I want to simplify the fraction represented by the `RationalNumber` using a callback function to another function (named `simplification`), but I receive some errors and I can't figure out what I am missing.

The first error is `cannot convert from 'void (__cdecl *)(RationalNumber &)' to 'RationalNumber::pointer_to_f'  Prob2   ...\source\repos\Prob2\Prob2\NumarRational.h    21`

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class RationalNumber {
    typedef void (RationalNumber::*pointer_to_f)(RationalNumber&);
private:
    int a;
    int b;

    void callback(pointer_to_f);
    static int gcd(int, int);
public:
    RationalNumber(int = 0, int = 0);
    static void simplification(RationalNumber&);
};

RationalNumber::RationalNumber(int x, int y) {
    this->a = x;
    this->b = y;
    pointer_to_f p = &simplification;    // <-- line 21, location of the first error
    callback((p)(this));

}

int RationalNumber::gcd(int a, int b)
{
    if (b == 0)
        return a;
    return gcd(b, a % b);
}

void RationalNumber::simplification(RationalNumber& x) {
    int d = gcd(x.a, x.b);
    if (d != 1) {
        x.a /= d;
        x.b /= d;
    }
}

void RationalNumber::callback(pointer_to_f *p(RationalNumber& x) ) {
    (*p)(x);
 }
```

The full error log:

```
Error   C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'void (__cdecl *)(RationalNumber &)' to 'RationalNumber::pointer_to_f'  Prob2   ...\source\repos\Prob2\Prob2\NumarRational.h    21

Error   C2511   'void RationalNumber::callback(RationalNumber::pointer_to_f *(__cdecl *)(RationalNumber &))': overloaded member function not found in 'RationalNumber'  Prob2   ...\source\repos\Prob2\Prob2\NumarRational.h    39

Error   C2065   'x': undeclared identifier  Prob2   ...\source\repos\Prob2\Prob2\NumarRational.h    40  

Error (active)  E0144   a value of type "void (*)(RationalNumber &x)" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "RationalNumber::pointer_to_f" Prob2   ...\source\repos\Prob2\Prob2\NumarRational.h    21  

Error (active)  E0147   declaration is incompatible with "void RationalNumber::callback(RationalNumber::pointer_to_f)" (declared at line 11 of "...\source\repos\Prob2\Prob2\NumarRational.h")  Prob2   ...\source\repos\Prob2\Prob2\NumarRational.h    39  

Error (active)  E0109   expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type Prob2   ...\source\repos\Prob2\Prob2\NumarRational.h    22

Error (active)  E0020   identifier "x" is undefined Prob2   ...\source\repos\Prob2\Prob2\NumarRational.h    40  

Error   C2064   term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments Prob2   ....source\repos\Prob2\Prob2\NumarRational.h    22
```

Thank you!

Comment: What do you want to use a callback and not directly call `RationalNumber::simplification`?

Comment: Why is simplification taking a reference to a RationalNumber as argument and not work on the class instance a and b directly?

Comment: Please include the errors in the question

Comment: A pointer-to-member-function (`pointer_to_f` in this code) has to be called on an object of the appropriate type: `(ptr->*pointer_to_f)(arg)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `cannot convert from 'void (__cdecl *)(RationalNumber &)' to 'RationalNumber::pointer_to_f'`

on the line

> `pointer_to_f p = &simplification;`

Let's see what we have here. This line initializes a variable (`p`) of type `RationalNumber::pointer_to_f`, which corresponds with what the attempted conversion is to. On the right-hand side of the `=` is the address of `RationalNumber::simplification`, a static member function from `RationalNumber&` to `void`. Check, that matches the error message.

So the first error comes down to the fact that a [pointer to member function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions) must point to a non-static member function. The address of a static member function is a normal function pointer (largely because it lacks the hidden `this` parameter).

Given your setup, it seems to make sense to remove the `static` keyword from `simplification` as well as removing its parameter. Have it operate on `*this`, which becomes available once the member function is no longer `static`.

Alternatively, you could change your pointers to member functions into regular pointers to functions, if for some reason `simplification` needs to be `static`. (Given that the function needs a `RationalNumber` object in either case, I don't see why `static` would be desirable.)

---

The remaining errors are technically independent, but I'll throw in some that have to do with invalid use of a pointer to member function.

> `callback((p)(this));`

This invokes the function pointed to by `p` and supplies the pointer `this` as an argument. The returned value (`void`) becomes the argument to `callback`. If you want to pass `p` as the argument to `callback`, then pass `p`:

```
callback(p);
```

> `void RationalNumber::callback(pointer_to_f *p(RationalNumber& x) )`

This does not match the declaration. You declared `callback` as a function whose parameter is a `pointer_to_f`. This definition has a parameter whose type is a function taking a `RationalNumber&` parameter and returning a `pointer_to_f` (the `x` is meaningless here). Be consistent!

```
void RationalNumber::callback(pointer_to_f p)
```

If you want to pass in something to use as the argument when `p` is invoked, you would need a second parameter. See also [Function pointer to member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402579/function-pointer-to-member-function) for how to fix the syntax you use to invoke `p`.

---

**Final note:** using a callback here looks like serious over-engineering, but I suppose the need for it might exist in details removed to make the example code simple.

Answer (score -1):

The bellow modified code compiles and shows how to use a static method as a "callback" but as stated above it si not clear why you do not want to directly use `simplification` method from the constructor (instead of using a pointer of this method)

```
 #include <functional>
class RationalNumber {

            private:
                int a;
                int b;


                static int gcd(int, int);
            public:
                RationalNumber(int = 0, int = 0);
                static void simplification(RationalNumber&);


            };

            RationalNumber::RationalNumber(int x, int y) {
                this->a = x;
                this->b = y;
                std::function<void(RationalNumber&)> p= &RationalNumber::simplification;
                p(*this) ;

            }
            int RationalNumber::gcd(int a, int b)
            {
                if (b == 0)
                    return a;
                return gcd(b, a % b);

            }
            void RationalNumber::simplification(RationalNumber& x) {
                int d = gcd(x.a, x.b);
                if (d != 1) {
                    x.a /= d;
                    x.b /= d;
                }
            }
```

Function pointers need to be static (cannot be object methods).
So in the above sample you could declare `gcd` and `simplification` as standard function (not object methods).

Comment: Yes, it might be possible to redesign the interface to get rid of this coding error. That's backwards: fix the coding error. Adding the overhead of `std::function` is one way to fix the coding error, but it's much better to simply write the function call correctly.

Comment: your last paragraph is wrong. There are pointers to non-static member functions, you just cannot use them to call the method without an instance.

Comment: Hello @idclev463035818. Do you have an example of using a object method directly as a callback?