# How to overload operator<< with a function as parameter (like endl for cout)?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

How to overload an `operator<<` with a function as parameter, like `std::endl` does for `std::cout`?

In my project, I need to do this. For example, in the following code:

```cpp
CSampleClass test;
test << CSampleClass::foo; // foo is function
```

I write code as following but it causes an error:

In the class header file:

```cpp
CSampleClass& foo(CSampleClass& c);
CSampleClass& operator << (CSampleClass& (*pf)(CSampleClass&));
```

In the class source file:

```cpp
CSampleClass& CSampleClass::foo(CSampleClass& c)
{
    // do some thing
    // for example set a variable in CSample class object
    // c.samevar = 0;
    return *this;
}

CSampleClass& CSampleClass::operator << (CSampleClass& (*pf)(CSampleClass&))
{   
    return *pf(*this);
}
```

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402579/function-pointer-to-member-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use `foo` with overload

```
CSampleClass& operator << (CSampleClass& (*pf)(CSampleClass&));
```

it needs to be a non-member function or a `static` member function.

Answer (score 2):

Non-static member functions are not like regular functions. Your operator should be declared like this

```
CSampleClass& operator << (CSampleClass& (CSampleClass::*pf)(CSampleClass&));
```

`CSampleClass& (CSampleClass::*pf)(CSampleClass&)` is a pointer to a member function (of the class CSampleClass).