# Method of object as method argument of another class in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, methods, arguments

I have an istance of a class A, that has some methods like:

```
class A
{
 ...
public:
 bool  DoOperation_one(Mytype*  pSomeValue);
 bool  DoOperation_two(Mytype*  pSomeValue);
 ... 
 bool  DoOperation_th(Mytype*  pSomeValue);
...
}
```

Another class, class B, has a pointer to A class and a method BMethod.

```
Class B
{
 ...
 A*  myPtrA;
...

bool  BMethod(...);   // arguments have to be defined
}
```

Is it possible to pass to BMethod, methods of A class instance as argument? I will try to be more clear with the follow pseudocode. In same place in class B i call BMethod with myPtrA method as argument (with parameters). I don't want to execute the myPtrA->DoOperation_two(somevalue) at calling time, but only in the BMethod (if statement):

```
    ...
    bool bVal = BMethod(myPtrA->DoOperation_two(somevalue))
    ...

bool B::BMethod("valid signature" myFunction)
{
 bool bfun=false;

  if (myFunction)
  {
    do_something....
  }

 return  bfun;
}
```

My goal is to call BMethod argument (DoOperation_one, DoOperation_two or DoOperation_th)   in the body of BMethod only. I have been used template, but DoOperation_XXX is executed at calling time.

```
....
bool bVal = BMethod(myPtrA->DoOperation_two(somevalue));

or

bool bVal = BMethod(myPtrA->DoOperation_one(somevalue));

...

     template <typename FunctionT>
         bool BMethod(FunctionT myFunc)
    {
          bool bfun=false;
          bool breturn = false;
    
          while (!bfun)
          {
            if (myFunc)
             {
              bfun=true;
              breturn = some_other_operation();
             }
           }
    
         return  breturn ;
    }
```

Moreover, myFunc contains result of myPtrA->DoOperation_one(somevalue), and doesn't change in the while statement because it has executed at calling time.

Is there any other approach/solution?

Comment: `bool bVal = BMethod(myPtrA->DoOperation_two(somevalue));` is passing the value returned from the method call to `BMethod`. Please clarify if you really need to pass the function or why simply passing its return value is not sufficient

Comment: `BMethod` would need the function and the parameter to call it. It is not clear what you mean when you write `if (myFunc)`. Is this supposed to call the function? Do you need to call the function in the loop (maybe because this is multithreaded and the value returned may change) ?

Comment: With bool bVal = BMethod(myPtrA->DoOperation_two(somevalue)) i need to pass function with its parameters

Comment: if (myFunc) : Here i call the function which will be called several times until some condition will be verified.

Comment: Your question isn't really that clear. *Maybe* you want to pass a variable function pointer as the first argument but, if so, [pointers to member functions have very tricky syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2402579/10871073).

Comment: i would like to pass pointer of instance methods. My goal is to use the same BMethod for all the methods of A Class (which have the same signature: bool DoOperation ...).  PS: sorry for my unclear question

Comment: OK - Then I guess it *is* a duplicate ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a member function pointer but then you'll need an `A` instance to call it and a `Mytype*` to be passed as parameter:

```
struct Mytype {};

struct A {
    bool  DoOperation_one(Mytype*  pSomeValue) { return true;}
    bool  DoOperation_two(Mytype*  pSomeValue) { return true;}
    bool  DoOperation_th(Mytype*  pSomeValue) { return true; }
};

struct B {
    A  a;
    template <typename F>
    bool  BMethod(F f,Mytype* mt) {
        bool bfun=false;
        bool breturn = false;
    
        while (!bfun) {
            if ((a.*f)(mt))
             {
              bfun=true;
              breturn = true;//some_other_operation();
             }
           }
    
         return  breturn ;
    }
};
int main() { 
    Mytype mt;
    B b;
    b.BMethod(&A::DoOperation_one,&mt);
}
```

Instead of making `BMethod` a template, I could have spelled out the type explcitly, it is `bool (A::*)(Mytype*)`. The syntax to call a member function pointer is a little clunky. If `a` is a pointer to `A` (like in your code) then it is `(a.->f)(mt)`.

Note that this only makes sense if the value returned from `A::DoOperation_xyz` changes while `B::BMethod` is executing. For example when multiple threads are involved. If thats the case you need to be careful with synchronizing access to shared data to avoid data races. If this isnt multi-threaded, I see no reason to make it complicated and `BMethod` can simply be `bool BMethod(bool x)`.