# Error: invalid use of member when calling methods on objects in static member function

Tags: c++

I have been getting the following error with this code:

```
class A {
    public:
        static void st() {
            (arr[5]->*n_st)();
        };
        void (A::*n_st)() {
            
        };
    private:
        static A *arr[10];
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

```
main.cpp: In static member function ‘static void A::st()’:
main.cpp:4:23: error: invalid use of member ‘A::n_st’ in static member function
    4 |             (arr[5]->*n_st)();
      |                       ^~~~
main.cpp:6:19: note: declared here
    6 |         void (A::*n_st)() {
      |                   ^~~~
```

I have laboriously looked for reasons and fixes to this error, but I cannot find similar code online. What is bugging me the most is that this code:

```
class A {
    public:
        static void st() {
            arr[5]->n_st();
        };
        void n_st() {
            
        };
    private:
        static A *arr[10];
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Compiles flawlessly. I thought the former code would compile as well.

What am I missing here? Which sort of code would make it work? It is crucial that `n_st` remains of type
`void (A::*)()`.

(PS: I am a bit of a noob, still learning pointers and such, so please be patient :D).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402579/function-pointer-to-member-function