# How can I have a struct with a variable with a pointer to a non-static member function?

Tags: c++, neural-network

I am creating a project related to Neural Networks. When getting the output, I want to have a neuron call the "ReturnValue" function of all the previous neurons. I've created a neuron class with said function. I want to be able to store these function pointers in a struct (to pair it with some other applicable data values), then store this struct in a vector. InTo summarize there will be one entry in the vector for every neuron in the previous layer. Each entry will be a struct containing a function pointer and a few other things. My problem is that I can't get the pointer to the function in the first place. Below is some code to illustrate.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct previous_neuron_struct {
    double weight;
    double (*funcPtr)(); //I think that this is correct
};

class neuron {
public:
    double value;
    std::vector<previous_neuron_struct> previous_neurons_vector;

    double Return_Value() {
        return value;
    }
};

int main() {
    neuron neuron1;
    neuron neuron2;
    //I know that it would be easier to avoid pointers, but this better illustrates the environment of the actual use case.
    previous_neuron_struct* temp = new previous_neuron_struct;
    temp->weight = 0.5;
    temp->funcPtr = neuron2.Return_Value; //<- Problem is here

//Rest of code
}
```

Line 25 is the problematic line. No combination of asterisks or ampersands that I have come across will allow me to put the address (not the return value) of neuron2.Return_Value() into temp->funcPtr. This sample code right now will give me Visual Studio error code 0300: `a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function`. But with a slightly different combination that I have seen on some tutorial websites, `neuron2.*Return_Value;` I get `Identifier "Return_Value" is undefined`. Thanks

Comment: The syntax is `returntype (classname::*variablename)(argstype)`

Comment: Note that _pointer-to-member-function_ cannot be used in isolation. You must invoke it on an actual object. So, your `previous_neuron_struct` also needs to store a pointer to a neuron (`neuron2` in this example). But `previous_neuron_struct` will also have a circular dependency on `neuron` and you should really define this struct _inside_ `neuron`. Worth noting that if you're always going to call `Return_Value` then you don't need to store a function pointer at all -- just store the neuron. For more modern techniques, consider `std::function` which is closer to what you're attempting.

Comment: Simple example of what you're attempting: https://godbolt.org/z/6qd6r73cY ... but see my comment above about this maybe _not_ being what you really need.

Comment: [How can I define a class member as a pointer to another member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402579/how-can-i-define-a-class-member-as-a-pointer-to-another-member-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring and calling member function pointers have a different syntax than for normal pointers. The syntax is as shown below:

```
struct previous_neuron_struct {
    double weight;
    double (neuron::*funcPtr)();  //syntax for declaring member function pointer 
};
int main() {
    //other code as before
    temp->funcPtr = &neuron::Return_Value; //works now
    std::invoke( temp->funcPtr, neuron1);  //call

    (neuron1.*(temp->funcPtr))();//another way of calling
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bd8G7oP6c)

Comment: Might also want to show the "raw" way of calling `temp->funcPtr`, viz something akin to `neuron1.*(temp->funcPtr)();` in `main()`.

Comment: @Peter Done. Note that there should be parenthesis in your given expression before `neuron1` and after `functPtr` otherwise it won't compile.