# How to invoke pointer to member function when it's a class data member?

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member, member-variables

```
struct B
{
  void (B::*pf)(int, int);  // data member
  B () : pf(&B::foo) {}
  void foo (int i, int j) { cout<<"foo(int, int)\n"; } // target method
};

int main ()
{
  B obj;
  // how to call foo() using obj.pf ?
}
```

In above test code, `pf` is a data member of `B`. What's the grammar rule to invoke it ? It should be straight forward, but I am not getting a proper match. e.g. If I try `obj.*pf(0,0);` then I get:

```
error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in ‘pf (...)’, e.g. ‘(... ->* pf) (...)’
```

Comment: see : http://ideone.com/p3a5G

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling C++ class methods via a function pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485983/calling-c-class-methods-via-a-function-pointer)

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功纳米比亚威视, No both are different. Your linked question explains, `"How to call class member using function pointer?"`, While I am asking `"<...same...>, when the function pointer itself is a class member also."`. Notice that answers to both the questions are different.

Comment: I agree that this has one extra step. but I felt it could be easily deduced once you know the function pointer syntax: `(obj.*ptr)`, just that here `ptr == (obj.ptr)`. But well, since you disagree I'll retract ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like this:

```
(obj.*obj.pf)(0, 1);
```

Member access (`.`) has a higher precedence than a pointer to member operator so this is equivalent to:

```
(obj.*(obj.pf))(0, 1);
```

Because function call also has higher precedence than a pointer to member operator, you can't do:

```
obj.*obj.pf(0, 1) /* or */ obj.*(obj.pf)(0, 1)
```

As that would be equivalent to:

```
obj.*(obj.pf(0, 1)) // grammar expects obj.pf to be a callable returning a
                    // pointer to member
```

Comment: +1, thx; it's unique; what would have happened if `obj` was a member of `B` ? :)

Comment: @iammilind: `obj` has type `B` so it can't be a member of `B` as it would imply a recursive class definition. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: No. even if there was a member like `obj` inside B; it won't be a problem until you have `(....)` enclosing the signature. I am clear with that problem now. So, either it will be a compile error or it will work fine.

Answer (score 5):

pf is a method pointer, and you want to invoke the method it points to, so you have to use

```
(obj.*obj.pf)(1, 2);
```

It says the object obj you invoke the method pointed by pf

See result here :

http://ideone.com/p3a5G

Answer (score 5):

The syntax is quite unnatural but a consequence of C++ precedence rules...

```
(obj.*obj.pf)(1, 2);
```