# How does Qt bind pointers-to-non-static-member-functions in QtConcurrent?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt4, qtconcurrent

From the [QtConcurrent documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtconcurrentrun.html#using-member-functions):

```
QByteArray bytearray = "hello world";
QFuture<QList<QByteArray> > future = QtConcurrent::run(bytearray, &QByteArray::split), ',');
...
QList<QByteArray> result = future.result();
```

The code snippet above appears to be binding a function in a similar way to `std::tr1::bind` (`std::bind` for > C++11). That is to say it's taking a non-static member function (`QByteArray::split()`) and (at some point later) calling it on the specific instance of the object of which it's a member (which we've supplied as `bytearray`).

How does Qt achieve this? Is it using `std::tr1::bind` or `boost::bind` somewhere behind the scenes?

[The documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtconcurrentrun.html#using-bound-function-arguments) does also refer to a case where you would use `std::tr1` or `boost` instead, but I don't fully understand what it means by a **bound function** in that context. Is the situation above in fact different/more specialised/simpler than other situations where you might otherwise use `tr1` or `boost`?

I've tried to make my way through the source but am getting lost very quickly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to attempt a self answer, as the existing answers (many thanks to @Mike Brown and @skyhisi) lay the groundwork but don't address this specific case...

**From the source:**

*QtConcurrent::run(...)* :

```
template <typename T, typename Class>
QFuture<T> run(const Class &object, T (Class::*fn)())
{
  return (new QT_TYPENAME SelectStoredMemberFunctionCall0<T, Class>::type(fn, object))->start();
}
```

*SelectStoredMemberFunctionCall0*:

```
template <typename T, typename Class>
struct SelectStoredMemberFunctionCall0
{
  typedef typename SelectSpecialization<T>::template
    Type<StoredMemberFunctionCall0    <T, Class>,
      VoidStoredMemberFunctionCall0<T, Class> >::type type;
};
```

*VoidStoredMemberFunctionCall0*:

```
template <typename T, typename Class>
class VoidStoredMemberFunctionCall0 : public RunFunctionTask<T>
{
public:
  VoidStoredMemberFunctionCall0(T (Class::*_fn)() , const Class &_object)
  : fn(_fn), object(_object){ }

  void runFunctor()
  {
    (object.*fn)();
  }
private:
  T (Class::*fn)();
  Class object;
};
```

Given the above, I can see that Qt stores a pointer-to-member-function in the [normal way](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html), but by dressing it up in templates which would otherwise go unnoticed, the illusion of generic-ness is created.

The type of `VoidStoredMemberFunctionCall0::object` as well as the signature of `VoidStoredMemberFunctionCall0::fn` are all specified above in the arguments passed to `QtConcurrent::run`.

*I wasn't aware that this 'implicit' templatization was even possible, to be honest. Would anybody be able to recommend further reading?*

Comment: I've found the book [The C++ Programming Language](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/3rd.html) very useful for understanding C++. The [C++ FAQ Templates](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html) page also has good explanations of many aspects of templates.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ FAQ explains [Pointers to member functions](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html) very well and explains the pitfalls.

At some point there would be a line similar to:

```
ret_val = obj_ptr->*func_ptr(param);
```

But it will be wrapped up in templates to allow passing any object type and parameter type, and there will be the thread dispatching mixed up in there as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a Function Pointer and an Instance of the Class the function was declared on. Invoking it is as simple as dereferencing the function pointer from the object. [This StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316751/how-to-invoke-pointer-to-member-function-when-its-a-class-data-member) shows the answer

Comment: I understand that `QtConcurrent::run` must be using a pointer to member function, I just don't understand how it stores the pointer/invokes the function on it when the function return type, args and the object of which it is a member aren't hard coded in `QtConcurrent` but are instead extracted from the args supplied to `run(...)`.