# VC++ Function Pointers in Class

Tags: c++, class, visual-c++, function-pointers

LASReader.h

```
class LASReader
{

public:

LASReader();
~LASReader();

Point3 (LASReader::*GetPoint)();

private:

Point3 GetPointF0();
Point3 GetPointF1();
Point3 GetPointF2();
Point3 GetPointF3();
Point3 GetPointF4();
Point3 GetPointF5();
};
```

LASReader.cpp

```
switch (m_header.PointDataFormat)
{
case 0:
    m_formatSize = sizeof(LASPOINTF0);
    GetPoint = &LASReader::GetPointF0;
    break;
case 1:
    m_formatSize = sizeof(LASPOINTF1);
    GetPoint = &LASReader::GetPointF1;
    break;
case 2:
    m_formatSize = sizeof(LASPOINTF2);
    GetPoint = &LASReader::GetPointF2;
    break;
case 3:
    m_formatSize = sizeof(LASPOINTF3);
    GetPoint = &LASReader::GetPointF3;
    break;
case 4:
    m_formatSize = sizeof(LASPOINTF4);
    GetPoint = &LASReader::GetPointF4;
    break;
case 5:
    m_formatSize = sizeof(LASPOINTF5);
    GetPoint = &LASReader::GetPointF5;
    break;
default:
    break;  // Unknown Point Data Format
}
```

main.cpp

```
Point3 p = reader->GetPoint;
```

"Error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'Point3 (__cdecl LASReader::* )(void)' to 'Point3'"

When I use bracelets

```
Point3 p = reader->GetPoint();
```

"Error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `(reader->*reader->GetPoint)()` to call it. See [How to invoke pointer to member function when it's a class data member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316751/how-to-invoke-pointer-to-member-function-when-its-a-class-data-member)

Comment: Ok I understand but now I had a "_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)" problem which trying to delete Point3 multiple times

Comment: There's nothing in the code you've posted that even has a `Point3` pointer.

Comment: Nope, the problem continues. Point3 going out of scope why?

Comment: GetPointF() functions are like this:

    Point3 GetPointF0()
    {
        Vector3 position = Vector3(pointData.X, pointData.Y, pointData.Z);
 
 position = position * *m_scale + *m_offset;

 return Point3(position);
    }

Point3 holds position as Vector3* and here it's ctor:

    Point3::Point3(Vector3 position)
    {
 m_position = new Vector3(position.X, position.Y, position.Z);
    }

Comment: Most likely, it's a rule of three thing. You need a copy constructor and assignment operator.

Comment: Before I've used function pointer it was not a problem.

 Point3 p = reader->GetPoint();

Answer (score -1):

Function pointer syntax goes as follows

```
returnType (*yourFuncName)(argumentTypes);
```

so you'll need to redefine your member to something like this

```
Point3 (*getPointFunc)(void);
```

Comment: It seems that it is illegal in VC++. Function pointers in class members must define like I did otherwise it cause compiler error C2276

Comment: Weird, I actually did it