# Passing an instance method to an API that expects a C function pointer

Tags: c++

I have a C API to a data source. To be notified that new data is available you give the API a callback in the form of a function pointer; your callback will be called when data comes in. The API’s header contains lines like this:

```
struct DataRecord { ... };
typedef void (*DataCallback)(DataRecord *data);

void set_data_callback(DataCallback processor);
```

My C++ class has an instance method with the signature

```
void MyClass::process_data(DataRecord *data);
```

and in the constructor of MyClass I’d like to set the new instance’s `process_data` method as the data callback for the C API. Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1485990/371228) I tried to write this code in the constructor:

```
typedef void (MyClass::data_callback_t)(DataRecord*);
data_callback_t callback = &MyClass::process_data;
set_data_callback(callback);
```

When I do this I get the error

> error C2664: 'set_data_callback' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'data_callback_t' to 'DataCallback'
>
> There is no context in which this conversion is possible

(I am using Visual C++ 2010 Express, although I hope that doesn’t make a difference.)

How can I extract a C function pointer from an instance and a method?

Comment: Short answer is, you can't.  Unless you're prepared to hardcode which instance is to be invoked, and then you can have a non-member such as `void process(DataRecord *data) { someInstance->process_data(data); }`.  To get round that limitation, you'd need to modify the API to take a `void *stuff` when registering the callback.

Comment: That's a really bad API, which does not allow passing a context-pointer... there are some non-standard libraries to create trampolines at runtime, and other flawed methods using static (or thread-local) variables. - - It's not quite as dire if the function does not return until it called the callback for the last time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. `MyClass::process_data` can be thought of as a `void(MyClass*, DataRecord*)`, which is the wrong type. You'd have to wrap your class pointer into the call somehow.

One approach might be to introduce a type with a static pointer:

```
struct MyClassCallbackHelper
{
    static MyClass* myClass;

    static void callback(DataRecord* record) {
        myClass->process_data(record);
    }
};
```

So that you can do:

```
MyClassCallbackHelper::myClass = this;
set_data_callback(&MyClassCallbackHelper::callback);
```

Comment: I believe a callback helper like this will work for my application. Thanks!