# Calling C++ class methods via a function pointer using boost::function

Tags: c++, boost

I want to use pointers to a class method using boost,
I saw this answer in stackoverflow that has an example of using boost:

[Calling C++ class methods via a function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485983/calling-c-class-methods-via-a-function-pointer)

However when I am trying to add a more complicated function,I don't know how to call it using boost:
How can I call the bark2 function in a similar way that bark1 is called?

```
struct dogfood
{
    int aa;
};

class Dog
{
public:
    Dog(int i) : tmp(i) {}
    void bark()
    {
        std::cout << "woof: " << tmp << std::endl;
    }

    int bark2(int a, dogfood *b)
    {
        return(6);
    }
private:
    int tmp;
};

int main()
{
   Dog* pDog1 = new Dog (1);
   Dog* pDog2 = new Dog (2);

   //BarkFunction pBark = &Dog::bark;
   boost::function<void (Dog*)> f1 = &Dog::bark;

   f1(pDog1);
   f1(pDog2);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not std::function? It was added to the standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
boost::function<int (Dog*, int, dogfood*)> f2 = &Dog::bark2;
```

and call it like

```
f2(pDog2, 10, nullptr); // or pass the required pointer
```

BTW, in C++11 you can simply use `std::function` from `#include <functional>` instead. Alternatively, you can use [`std::mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn) (also since C++11), like

```
auto f3 = std::mem_fn(&Dog::bark2);
f3(pDog2, 42, nullptr);
```

The latter is a thin wrapper around a pointer-to-member-function and should probably perform better than the more "heavier" `std::function`.

Comment: what is the meaning or the function of the  "void" in       boost::function<void (Dog*, int, dogfood*)> f2 = &Dog::bark2;  ?

Comment: @user2162793 It represents the return type of the function

Comment: but bark2 returns int:  int bark2(int a, dogfood *b)

Comment: ohhh I made a typo then. The code compiles because `std:function` greedily accepts almost everything. Thanks for pointing it.