# C++ pass function pointer with parameter to function

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I think I have misunderstood how function pointers work.  In this example:

```
class Helper
{
  public:

      typedef void (*SIMPLECALLBK)(const char*);
      Helper(){};
      void NotifyHelperbk(SIMPLECALLBK pCbk)
      { m_pSimpleCbk = pSbk; }
  private:
     SIMPLECALLBK m_pSimpleCbk;

}

// where i call the func
class Main
{
    public:
      Main(){};
    private:
      Helper helper
      void SessionHelper(const char* msg);

}

Main.cpp

void Main::SessionHelper(const char* msg)
{
   ....
} 

helper.NotifyHelperbk(&Main::SessionHelper);
```

I get the following error:

```
error C2664: 'Main::NotifyHelperbk' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'void (__thiscall Main::* )(const char *)' to 'Helper::SIMPLECALLBK'
1>        There is no context in which this conversion is possible
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485983/calling-c-class-methods-via-a-function-pointer Your function pointer actually has the signature `void (Main::*SIMPLECALLBK)(const char*)` which is not what your `typedef` says

Comment: You're missing a `;` after the declaration of `helper` in your `Main` class. I doubt that's it though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Main::SessionHelper` is a non static method. So add `static` to it to be able to use it as function pointer. Or use member method pointer (you will need a instance to call it).

Comment: why its needs to be static ?

Comment: @user63898 non-static member functions can only be called on an object. There is no object associated with `&Main::SessionHelper`

Answer (score 0):

if you use c++11 you can use  [std::bind](http://fr.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

```
class Helper
{
  public:
    void NotifyHelperbk(std::function<void(char*)> func){
    /* Do your stuff */
    func("your char* here");
}
```

And your main :

```
Main.cpp

Main m;

helper.NotifyHelperbk(std::bind(&Main::SessionHelper, m, std::placeholder_1));
```