# C++ - function pointers and class

Tags: c++, function, class, pointers

While I was trying to compile this piece of code to implement the concept of function pointer using classes in C++:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class sorting
{
public:
void bubble_sort(int *arr, int size, bool (*compare)(int,int))
{
    int i,j,temp = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        for(j = i+1; j < size; j++)
        {
            if(compare(arr[i],arr[j]))
            {
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j]  = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

bool ascending(int x,int y)
{
    return x > y;
}

bool descending(int x,int y)
{
    return x < y;
}

void display(int *arr,int size)
{
    for(int index = 0; index < size; index++)
    {
        cout<<"arr["<<index<<"]:"<<arr[index]<<endl;
    }
}
};

int main()
{
    int arr[10] = {99,77,22,33,88,55,44,66,11,100};

    sorting s;
    cout<<"Ascending order"<<endl;
    s.bubble_sort(arr,10,&sorting::ascending);
    s.display(arr,10);

    cout<<"Descending order"<<endl;
    s.bubble_sort(arr,10,&sorting::descending);
    s.display(arr,10);

    return 0;
}
```

I got errors in these lines:

```
s.bubble_sort(arr,10,&sorting::ascending);
s.bubble_sort(arr,10,&sorting::descending);
```

The errors are:

```
error C2664: 'sorting::bubble_sort' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'bool (__thiscall sorting::* )(int,int)' to 'bool (__cdecl *)(int,int)'
```

for both the lines.
Can somebody help me to eliminate these errors?

Comment: Easiest solution? Make the comparison functions `static`. Then repeat after me: A pointer to a function is *not* the same thing as a pointer to a *member function*.

Comment: The simplest fix is to mark `ascending` and `descending ` as `static`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method is to make the definitions of `ascending` and `descending` static functions either inside or outside the class definition, or by moving the function declaration/definition outside of the class' scope:

```
static bool ascending(int x,int y)
{
    return x > y;
}

static bool descending(int x,int y)
{
    return x < y;
}
```

The compiler sees the functions defined in the class as member functions using the `__thiscall` calling convention, while normal C++ function pointers use the `__cdecl` calling convention by default (it can be modified manually). Moving the definitions outside of the class gives the functions the `__cdecl` modifier automatically. Marking the functions as `static` also gives them the `__cdecl` modifier.

Answer (score 2):

`ascending` and `descending` are member function, therefeore they can only be called on `sorting` class member (and actually have three arguments, not two).

Make them `static` functions, or, even better, change `sorting` from `class` to `namespace`: there is no reason for it to be a class.

Answer (score 1):

`sorting::ascending` and `sorting::descending` should be declared as `static`, or not as a member at all, because they don't operate on `*this` instance. That's how you know a function should be `static` (or non-member).

Without them declared as `static`, the syntax for a member function pointer is different, and you also need a dummy instance to make the call.

Answer (score 1):

Function pointers in C++ are slightly different. Unlike C, member functions are not always 'globally' accessible unless made `static`. When made `static` there is only one address location of the function for any number of instances of that class. Your code with this method will be:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class sorting
{
public:
void bubble_sort(int *arr, int size, bool (*compare)(int,int))
{
    int i,j,temp = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        for(j = i+1; j < size; j++)
        {
            if(compare(arr[i],arr[j]))
            {
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j]  = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

static bool ascending(int x,int y)
{
    return x > y;
}

static bool descending(int x,int y)
{
    return x < y;
}

void display(int *arr,int size)
{
    for(int index = 0; index < size; index++)
    {
        cout<<"arr["<<index<<"]:"<<arr[index]<<endl;
    }
}
};

int main()
{
    int arr[10] = {99,77,22,33,88,55,44,66,11,100};

    sorting s;
    cout<<"Ascending order"<<endl;
    s.bubble_sort(arr,10,&sorting::ascending);
    s.display(arr,10);

    cout<<"Descending order"<<endl;
    s.bubble_sort(arr,10,&sorting::descending);
    s.display(arr,10);

    return 0;
}
```

Another method to do the same is by using the `.*` or `->*` keywords. They are used together with an instance of a class in order to call one of their (non-static) member functions. If the call takes place within another member function you may use the this-pointer. Read [here](http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html#defi) for more details. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485983/calling-c-class-methods-via-a-function-pointer). Your code will then be:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class sorting
{
public:
void bubble_sort(int *arr, int size, bool (sorting::*compare)(int,int))
{
    int i,j,temp = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        for(j = i+1; j < size; j++)
        {
            if((this->*compare)(arr[i],arr[j]))
            {
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j]  = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

bool ascending(int x,int y)
{
    return x > y;
}

bool descending(int x,int y)
{
    return x < y;
}

void display(int *arr,int size)
{
    for(int index = 0; index < size; index++)
    {
        cout<<"arr["<<index<<"]:"<<arr[index]<<endl;
    }
}
};

int main()
{
    int arr[10] = {99,77,22,33,88,55,44,66,11,100};

    sorting s;
    cout<<"Ascending order"<<endl;
    s.bubble_sort(arr,10,&sorting::ascending);
    s.display(arr,10);

    cout<<"Descending order"<<endl;
    s.bubble_sort(arr,10,&sorting::descending);
    s.display(arr,10);

    return 0;
}
```