# Problems with GLUT callback functions

Tags: c++, glut

Hei,

I am trying to create a scene with OpenGL and CUDA using C++ but i receive an error when i try to pass the function for initialization.
Here is my header :

```
class SimpleScene
{
public:

    SimpleScene();
    ~SimpleScene();
    void computeFPS();
    void render();
    void display();
    void idle();
    void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y);
    void reshape(int x, int y);
    void cleanup();
    void initGLBuffers();
    uchar *loadRawFile(const char *filename, size_t size);
    void initGL(int *argc, char **argv);
    int chooseCudaDevice(int argc, char **argv, bool bUseOpenGL);
    void runAutoTest(const char *ref_file, char *exec_path);
    void loadVolumeData(char *exec_path);
};
```

And in my .cpp file i have something like this and this generete same errors:

```
void SimpleScene::initGL(int * argc, char ** argv)
{
SimpleScene* obj = new SimpleScene;
// initialize GLUT callback functions
glutInit(argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE);
glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
glutCreateWindow("CUDA 3D texture");
glutDisplayFunc(obj->display);
glutKeyboardFunc(obj->keyboard);
glutReshapeFunc(obj->reshape);
glutIdleFunc(obj->idle);

if (!isGLVersionSupported(2, 0) || !areGLExtensionsSupported("GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object"))
    {
    fprintf(stderr, "Required OpenGL extensions are missing.");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

The problems are in the display,idle,keybord and reshape. The errors reported are like this:

```
Error   C3867   'SimpleScene::display': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member  
Error   C3867   'SimpleScene::idle': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member     
Error   C3867   'SimpleScene::keyboard': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member 
Error   C3867   'SimpleScene::reshape': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0x1aatf.aspx

Answer (score 1):

From experience I can tell you glut works really bad with OOP architecture there is an answer on another question that can help about c++ pointers this is the link to it [How to make a pointer to a method in class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485983/calling-c-class-methods-via-a-function-pointer).

Answer (score 0):

You should program like this:

- glutDisplayFunc(this->display)

rather than

- glutDisplayFunc(obj->display)