# how to initialize function pointer to class member?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, compilation

I would like to pass a function pointer along with type fnptr_t.  However it is a member of Box class. When I compile this code I get this error. What does this mean and how can I fix it?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct direction{
    int i;
};

typedef void (*fnptr_t)(struct direction *);

class Box
{
public:
    Box(int size = 3);
    ~Box(void);

    void fall(struct direction *d){printf("fnptr\n");}

};

int main()
{
    /* main.cpp:26*/ fnptr_t ptr = &Box::fall;

}
```

Error:

```
main.cpp:26:26: error: cannot convert 'void (Box::*)(direction*)' to 'fnptr_t {aka void (*)(direction*)}' in initialization                                                                         
  fnptr_t ptr = &Box::fall;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485983/calling-c-class-methods-via-a-function-pointer

Comment: or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402579/function-pointer-to-member-function or dozens more. Searching for `[cpp] pointer to member function` will yield many related questions.