# C++ calling a function pointer stored in a struct in a map

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, function-pointers, stdmap

I am getting the error `term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments` when trying to call a function pointer.

The function pointer is stored in a struct. The struct is then stored in a map.
Definition:

```
typedef void (CLIOptions::*OptionHandler)(QString);

struct OptionDefinition {
   QString name;
   QString description;
   QString type;
   OptionHandler handler;
};

typedef std::map<QString, OptionDefinition> CLIOptionMap;
```

I initialise the map like this:

```
CLIOptionMap optionMap =
{
   {
      QString("set-tcp-host"),
      {
         QString("set-tcph"),
         QString("Set the TCP server host address"),
         QString("string"),
         &CLIOptions::setTcpHost
      }
   },
  // etc...
}
```

The problem occurs when I try to iterate through the map and call the handler:

```
for (it = optionMap.begin(); it != optionMap.end(); ++it) {
    QString value = /*snip...*/

    (it->second.handler)(value)
}
```

What is my problem here?

Comment: How would the line of code you wrote know what instance of CLIOptions to call that member function on?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485983/calling-c-class-methods-via-a-function-pointer me thinks

Comment: @EdgarRokyan : No.  `it->second.handler` is the pmf.  You then need something like `this->*(it->second.handler)(value)`.  This is complicated enough, I recommend an intermediate variable for readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't have a function pointer, you have a *pointer to member function*, and they are very different beasts.  A pointer-to-member-function isn't even a pointer in general (it has to be able to handle pointer to a virtual function in a second virtual base class!)

Given you have a pmf, you need an object to invoke the pmf *on*.  So something like:

```
for (it = optionMap.begin(); it != optionMap.end(); ++it) {
    QString value = /*snip...*/
    const auto pmf = it->second.handler;
    (mOptionHandler.*pmf)(value);
}
```

actually, if you going to use C++11 `auto`, you can also use the foreach loop:

```
for (const auto& option : optionMap) {
   const auto pmf = option.handler;
   (mOptionHandler.*pmf)(option.value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So I have an instance of "CLIOptions" available called ``mOptionHandler``, so I setup the call like ``(mOptionHandler.pmf)`` but this gives ``CLIOptions has no member pmf``

Comment: Oh I just missed a dereference I think: ``mOptionHandler.*pmf``

Comment: I've changed my example to use your name.  And yes - the `.*` operator is completely different to the `.` operator!