# Arduino: Calling serial.begin() on a Stream object

Tags: c++, inheritance, arduino

I am trying to modify [this class](https://github.com/mikeshub/FUTABA_SBUS/tree/master/FUTABA_SBUS) so that I can use both *SoftwareSerial* and *HardwareSerial* objects. I therefore added a constructor that takes in a *Stream* object, the superclass of both Software and HardwareSerial:

```
/**
 * Instantiates an SBUS object
 * @param Stream* A HardwareSerial or SoftwareSerial object pointer
 */
SBUS::SBUS(const Stream *serialPort){
    port = serialPort;
}
```

Unfortunately, in the `SBUS::begin()` method I must call `port->begin(BAUDRATE)`, and although `begin()` exists as a method in both subclasses, because it is not in the *Stream* superclass, I cannot call it.

How can I call `port->begin()`? I have tried to call `begin()` on the Hardware or SoftwareSerial object externally in between SBUS construction and the `SBUS::begin()` method, but this does not seem to initialize the *SBUS* object properly. Is there a way to call `begin()` from inside the *SBUS* class?

I greatly appreciate any help. (*FUTABA_SBUS* was changed to *SBUS* for ease of programming)

Comment: What is the exact problem when you try to call `port->begin()` in `SBUS::begin()`?  The `const` in the constructor looks fishy.

Comment: I didn't even notice the const! But unfortunately that's not the issue. Even when I remove it I get this error: `'class Stream' has no member named 'begin'`.

Comment: That compiler error is correct, since the `Stream` class [doesn't have such function](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/stream/), so why do you think you need it?

Comment: Exactly. I agree with the compiler here (In my original question: "it is not in the *Stream* superclass"). However, I need to initialize my *SoftwareSerial* and *HardwareSerial* objects with some baud rate inside the SBUS class, and I am unsure of how to do so, since I cannot initialize Stream objects.

Comment: Maybe set the baud rate before you construct the SBUS object?

Comment: Well, the answer is simple, add an according function to the class hierarchy, so you can call it. If that makes your design any better, I don't know, I have my doubts though.

Comment: @john In my situation I do not believe I can. The baud rate can only be set in the `setup()` or `loop()` functions in the Arduino script, but SBUS must be executed afterwards. I need a global SBUS scope, but this confines me to local scopes, in the `setup()` or `loop()` functions.

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt I guess I'm afraid of messing with the stock Arduino library, and unsure of how to implement a modified library in my program. I was hoping for a different way of doing this, but if that's my only option...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some possibilities:

- Initialize the Serial before passing it by a pointer
- You can add coresponding method to the Stream class and make it virtual

  virtual begin(long x) {}

so that the compiler stops complaining and uses the correct method for the object.

- [Pass a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1486279/2369817) to the correct begin(..) method to your constructor, save it and call it whenever you like
- You can create multiple constructors(likely the best solution):

  `bool hwSerial;
  Stream * port;
  SBUS::SBUS(SoftwareSerial * serial)    {hwserial = false; port = serial;}
  SBUS::SBUS(HWSerial * serial)          {swserial = true;  port = serial;}`

  Then you can do something like this:

  `SBUS::portBegin(long baudrate) {
  if(hwserial) {
    static_cast<HWSerial*>(port)->begin(baudrate);
  } else {
    static_cast<SoftwareSerial*>(port)->begin(baudrate);
  }`

  --EDIT--
  Corrected, dynamic -> static cast

Comment: You're right; creating multiple constructors is the best solution, although as @Oleg Moiseenko pointed out, a `static_cast` must be used, since the Arduino AVR compiler does not support `dynamic_cast` without enabling RTTI, which is probably a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

static_cast because for dynamic_cast you have to enable RTTI

```
bool hwSerial;
Stream * port;
SBUS::SBUS(SoftwareSerial * serial)    {hwserial = false; port = serial;}
SBUS::SBUS(HardwareSerial * serial)          {swserial = true;  port = serial;}

Then you can do something like this: 
SBUS::portBegin(long baudrate) {
if(hwserial) {
  static_cast<HardwareSerial*>(port)->begin(baudrate);
} else {
  static_cast<SoftwareSerial*>(port)->begin(baudrate);
}
```