# Confirm Understanding about Pointers to Functions

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

As a C++ learner, I came across the following piece of code from C++ Language Tutorial and got two questions, could any expert provide some guidance on those?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int addition (int a, int b)
{ return (a+b); }
int subtraction (int a, int b)
{ return (a-b); }
int operation (int x, int y, int
(*functocall)(int,int))
{
  int g;
  g = (*functocall)(x,y);
  return (g);
}
int main () {
  int m,n;
  int (*minus)(int,int) = subtraction;
  m = operation (7, 5, addition);
  n = operation (20, m, minus);
  cout <<n;
  return 0;
}
```

In function "operation" definition:

Question 1: for "g = (*functocall)(x,y)", does it deference the pointer that points to a function (ex.subtraction) and assign it to g?

Question 2: for "return(g)", I'm wondering why we put parenthesis for g?

And for "int (*minus)(int,int) = subtraction;" in the main function, is that okay if we write the following instead?

int (*minus)(int,int)

minus = subtraction

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling C++ class methods via a function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485983/calling-c-class-methods-via-a-function-pointer)

Comment: Please take a look at our [recommended C++ book list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242).  Many "C++ language tutorials" are known for sporting glaringly obvious factual errors and promoting abysmally bad programming styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question 1: for `g = (*functocall)(x,y)`, does it deference the
>   pointer that points to a function (ex.subtraction) and assign it to g?

Answer: No.

```
(*functocall)(x,y);
```

is simply one allowable syntax for invoking the function from the pointer passed as a parameter. It is entirely equivalent to:

```
functocall(x,y);
```

Which simply eliminates the `(*...)` syntax which is allowable but unnecessary.

> Question 2: for `return(g)`, I'm wondering why we put parenthesis for
>   g?

The parenthesis too are discretionary and are superfluous to the return. Simply providing:

```
return g;
```

is all that is needed as there is no expression requiring evaluation priority provided by the enclosing `(..)`.

Answer (score 1):

Before I start, your code uses *way* more parenthesis than it needs.

Here is the same code, better formatted and reduced:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int addition (int a, int b)
{ return a+b; }
int subtraction (int a, int b)
{ return a-b; }
int operation (int x, int y, int (*functocall)(int,int))
{
  int g;
  g = functocall(x,y);
  return g;
}

int main () {
  int m,n;
  int (*minus)(int,int) = subtraction;
  m = operation (7, 5, addition);
  n = operation (20, m, minus);
  cout <<n<<"\n";

  return 0;
}
```

> for "g = (*functocall)(x,y)", does it deference the pointer that points to a function (ex.subtraction) and assign it to g?

In a nutshell - yes. When calling a function through it's pointer, it is not necessary to explicitly dereference it. I know, it's surprising and counter to the way pointers are typically used.

Think of it this way. Whenever you are just writing the name of a function, you are essentially getting the function's pointer. This is why you wrote as you did, rather than write:

```
  m = operation (7, 5, &addition);
```

You do not need to explicitly dereference when using a function pointer for the same reason you do not need to explicitly use the `address of` operator when taking its address in the first place.

> Question 2: for "return(g)", I'm wondering why we put parenthesis for g?

There is positively no good reason to. In fact, there is no reason to do it for any of your `return` statements.

> And for "int (*minus)(int,int) = subtraction;" in the main function,
>   is that okay if we write the following instead?
>
> ```
> int (*minus)(int,int);
> minus = subtraction;
> ```

Personally, I recommend you use:

```
int (*minus)(int,int) = nullptr;
minus = subtraction;
```

so as not to leave uninitialized variables, but otherwise, yes, absolutely. A pointer to function variable is just like any other variable.