# Array of pointers to MainWindow functions results in "void value not ignored as it ought to be"

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to create an array of pointers to MainWindow functions, because I need to loop and execute all of the functions associated with my pushbuttons and spinboxes automatically. Here is the sample code:

```
typedef void (*f_pointer)();

void MainWindow::on_test_spinBox_valueChanged(int a){
ui->label->setNum(a);
}

void MainWindow::on_test_pushButton_clicked() {
int a = 1 + 2;
}

void MainWindow::on_test2_pushButton_clicked() {
int a = 2 + 3;
}

void MainWindow::on_run_all_pushButton_clicked() {
f_pointer array[]  = { MainWindow::on_test_spinBox_valueChanged(), MainWindow::on_test2_pushButton_clicked(), MainWindow::on_test_pushButton_clicked() };

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
array[i];
}
```

All of this results in error: void value not ignored as it ought to be.

Can you help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The main error (that reported) is that, in your initializer list, you have *calls* to the three functions, rather than their addresses. You should remove the parentheses after the functions names to specify those functions' *addresses* rather than their returned values. But note: this can only be done for `static` class member functions; for non-static member functions, the syntax is trickier: [Calling C++ class methods via a function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485983/calling-c-class-methods-via-a-function-pointer).

Also, your first function in the list does not have the correct signature for its address to be an `f_pointer`, as it has an `int a` argument.

Comment: In my example all of the functions that I want to put in the array should have some int as an argument.

Updating typedef void (MainWindow::*f_pointer)(int);  and array initializer list with & seem to have resolved the original error. 

Is there a way for me to pass an int to each of the array items when I loop through it and execute?

Comment: @parameter2 Yes: if the `int` argument you want to pass is called (say) `x`, then you just need to add that as an argument after the array specifier: `array[i](x);` will call the function pointed to by the `i` element, with `x` as its argument.

Answer (score 0):

When building your list, this code:

```
MainWindow::on_test_spinBox_valueChanged()
```

Gives you the return value of that function. It will actually call it. What happens when you put a void in an array, I don't know. What you want is:

```
&MainWindow::on_test_spinBox_valueChanged
```

However, why do you do the loop? You already have a function that lists all the functions. Just call them instead. The array and loop just adds code to your project. Eg.

```
void MainWindow::on_run_all_pushButton_clicked() {
    MainWindow::on_...();
    ...
    MainWindow::on_...();
}
```

But, there is an even better way. You can daisy-chain signals. So make the `on_run_all_pushButton_clicked` a signal, then connect it to the `on_test_spinBox_valueChanged` and so on. See: http://thesmithfam.org/blog/2005/09/16/qt-connecting-signals-to-signals/ .