# Declaring an array of functions inside a class

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I have a batch of functions in a class:

```
class Edges // Edges of a Rubik's cube
{
    // Stuff
    
    protected:
        // Edges movements
        void e_U();
        void e_D();
        void e_F();
        void e_B();
        void e_R();
        void e_L();
        
    // More stuff
};
```

A new class inherits this functions:

```
class Cube: public Edges // Rubik's cube class
{
    public: 
        void U(int); // U slice edges movement relative to spin
        
    // Stuff
}
```

The call for the needed function depends on a number, as you see in the next code:

```
void Cube::U(int spin) // U slice movement for the given spin
{
    switch (spin)
    {
        case 0: e_U(); return;
        case 1: e_U(); return;
        case 2: e_U(); return;
        case 3: e_U(); return;
        case 4: e_D(); return;
        ...
        case 23: e_L(); return;
        default: return;
    }
}
```

I want to improve the performance, so I put the functions in an array:

```
class Cube: public Edges // Rubik's cube class
{
    public: 
        void U(int); // U slice edges movement relative to spin
        
    // Stuff
    
    private:
    
        const static void (*(USlice[24]))(); // U slice edges movement relative to spin
        
    // More stuff
}

const void Cube::( (*(USlice[24]))() ) =
{ 
    e_U, e_U, e_U, e_U,
    e_D, e_D, e_D, e_D,
    e_F, e_F, e_F, e_F,
    e_B, e_B, e_B, e_B,
    e_R, e_R, e_R, e_R,
    e_L, e_L, e_L, e_L
};
```

So the U function should be now something like this:

```
void Cube::U(int spin) // U slice movement for the given spin
{
    USlice[spin]();
}
```

My question is that I can't find the right way to declare the functions array inside the class. I've tried everything I can think of (remove "const" and "static" statements, make all public, ...)

The array should be "static" and "const", and the members are 24 "void" functions with no parameters.

Actually I don't know if declaring the functions in an array will be faster than using a switch statement, but I would like to check it.

Thanks.

Comment: look for member function pointers, they are fundamentally different than pointers to free functions. The members of the array are *not* just void functions with no parameter

Comment: `USlice` is an array of member function pointers, so the calling needs to be in context of a `Cube` object.   For example,   `(some_cube.*(USlice[spin]))()`   or `(some_pointer_to_a_cube->*(USlice[spin]))()`.    In a non-static member function, this can use the `this` pointer  e.g. `(this->*(USlice[spin]))()`

Comment: Please read [this](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485983/calling-c-member-functions-via-a-function-pointer this can help you.

Comment: The array can't be static. You need a different array for each instatiated object, if it should map to the member functions. Unless the member functions are also static.

Comment: Are there different pointers to the functions? I think there is only one pointer to each function and this pointer should not change during program execution, so I think that static should be admissible. Am I wrong?

Comment: This is the sort of thing that would benefit hugely from non-type template parameters. `void e_U` might very well be better expressed as `e<+1,0,0>( )` and `void e_L` then becomes `e<0,0,-1>( )`.

Comment: `std::array` has better syntax: `std::array<void(C::*)(), 24>USlice;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is that `e_U`, `e_D`, etc are all member functions, and not just plain functions, so the type of pointers to them are pointer-to-member functions.

The declaration and usage for your array would look like:

```cpp
class Cube : public Edges {
    // ...
    static void (Cube::* const USlice[24])();
};

void (Cube::* const Cube::USlice[24])() = {
    &Cube::e_U, &Cube::e_U, &Cube::e_U, &Cube::e_U,
    &Cube::e_D, &Cube::e_D, &Cube::e_D, &Cube::e_D,
    &Cube::e_F, &Cube::e_F, &Cube::e_F, &Cube::e_F,
    &Cube::e_B, &Cube::e_B, &Cube::e_B, &Cube::e_B,
    &Cube::e_R, &Cube::e_R, &Cube::e_R, &Cube::e_R,
    &Cube::e_L, &Cube::e_L, &Cube::e_L, &Cube::e_L
};

void Cube::U(int spin) {
    (this->*USlice[spin])();
}
```

Alternatively you can make all your functions into static functions and make the `this` parameter explicit (`void e_U();` -> `static void e_U(Edges&);`), and you can store those as function pointers

---

However, the version with the array isn't particularly optimised. gcc and clang still have a lot of overhead to deal with pointers to virtual functions. The switch version becomes optimised to a (better) lookup table and a simple jump to the value in the table, just  like you want. This pattern is very easy to optimise into a table, so your compiler should already be doing it.

See here for a disassembly: https://godbolt.org/z/beaPYvzMY (The switch LUT is labelled `.L4`, the explicit pointer-to-member table is labelled `Cube::U_lookup(int)::table`)

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer is exactly what I needed! I've tested it in my code and works perfect! I need to do some adjustmenst and I will perform some performace tests .

Comment: I suggest `std::array` usage with simpler/more intuitive syntax.

Comment: @Artyer You are right. I did several tests using switch statements and functions arrays and there is no significant difference at run time with the optimized code. Thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, for only performance, you don't need to use array of function pointers.

There is no speed difference.
Using function pointers, it tooks 1 MOV operation in asm(about 2 DWORD), while using switch tooks 1~2 CMP or TEST operations(about 2-6 WORD, because there are only 6 unique functions in 24sets).

The errors you mentioned is that, values of array are the function pointers to protected member function - not global function.
This means, you have to think about 1st function  parameter is `*this` which is invisible to c++ code.

Comment: Actually there will be more functions in the array, at least 18, but can be more. I put only six to simplify the question.

Comment: @GRVigo Then, function pointer will be faster. Try reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485983/calling-c-member-functions-via-a-function-pointer , it can help you a little.

Answer (score 2):

The function pointers that you want to keep inside the array are pointers to the methods of a `Cube` object. But you want to define that array member variable as an static variable. And as you know, static variables can be accessed without any class objects. So, this is a contradiction.

You can write your class like this without the array to be static.

```
class Cube : public Edges // Rubik's cube class
{
public:
   Cube() :
      mFuncs{ 
         std::bind(&Cube::e_U, this),
         std::bind(&Cube::e_U, this),
         std::bind(&Cube::e_U, this), 
         std::bind(&Cube::e_U, this), 
         std::bind(&Cube::e_D, this),
         std::bind(&Cube::e_L, this) }
   {
   }

   void e_U() {}
   void e_D() {}
   void e_L() {}

   void U(size_t spin) // U slice edges movement relative to spin
   {
      if (spin < mFuncs.size())
      {
         mFuncs[spin]();
      }
      else
      {
         // report the error
      }
   }
protected:
   const std::vector<std::function<void()>> mFuncs;
// Stuff
};
```