# How to call member function pointer where it is not in class itself?

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

```
struct CALLBACK_DATA
{
    Object *pointer;
    void (Object::*callback)();
};

int main()
{
    CALLBACK_DATA data = getData();
    //This isn't working.
    (data.pointer)->(data.*callback)();
}
```

Here callback pointer is not inside class Object but it is inside CALLBACK_DATA.

How to make it work?

Thank you,
Praveen Kumar.

Comment: please post a [mcve] together with the error message. What is the meaning of `This isn't working` ?

Comment: If you need to store a function, I recommend you start with [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). While it have its cons, it's just so much simpler to handle.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a pointer to a member function and call it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485983/how-can-i-create-a-pointer-to-a-member-function-and-call-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation is incorrect. It does not point to the `data.callback` directly. What you should do is move `*` here:

```cpp
(data.pointer->*(data.callback))();
```