# How can I define an array of functions in a C++ class and initialize them in the constructor?

Tags: c++, oop

This is my class:

```
class Cpu
{
  private:
    typedef uint8_t(Cpu::*OpCode)();
    OpCode *op_codes; // How can I define an array of 256 function pointers?

    uint8_t op_nop();
    uint8_t op_lxi();
    uint8_t op_stax();
    uint8_t op_mov();
    uint8_t op_mvi();
    ...
};
```

Then I would like to initiate the array in the class constructor:

```
Cpu::Cpu()
{
   op_codes = new OpCode[256] {
            // 0x00
            &Intel8080::op_nop,
            // 0x01
            &Intel8080::op_lxi,
            // 0x02:
            &Intel8080::op_stax,
            // 0x03
     ...
}
```

And finally I would like to use the array:

```
void Cpu::SingleStep()
    {
        uint8_t op_code = 0x00;
        *op_codes[op_code](); // How can I execute the specified function?
    }
```

I tried to define the field in the class using various examples.

```
OpCode op_codes[256];
```

But how can I assign the functions?

Comment: *"but how to assign then functions?"* - `op_codes[0x42] = &Intel8080::foo;`. Arguably this is better than putting the opcode index into a comment, becaues the comment can be wrong.

Comment: Prefer a plain array (not pointer + `new`) for fixed-size arrays. Or `std::array`.

Comment: I'd make this a static array if it doesn't have information specific to a particular instance. Then you'd initialize it similarly to global variables instead of in the constructor.

Comment: As for "how to call it", `std::invoke(op_codes[op_code], this)`. There is syntax to do it directly, but I think it is cryptic.

Comment: ```std::invoke(op_codes[op_code], this);``` // I get the error: namespace "std" has no member "invoke"

Comment: [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) was added to `<functional>` header in C++17.

Comment: functins need access to class fields, I cannot define theme as static - I do not want to pass Cpu as parameter to every metchod.

Comment: ```op_codes[0x42] = &Intel8080::foo;``` // I would prefer to assign the array in single line like:

```
op_codes = {
            // 0x00

            &Intel8080::op_nop,

            // 0x01
            &Intel8080::op_lxi,

            // 0x02:
            &Intel8080::op_stax,
...
```

Comment: looks like the definition works:
```
private:
   typedef uint8_t(Intel8080::*OpCode)();
   std::array<OpCode, 256> op_codes;
```
I can initialize it:

```
op_codes = {
            // 0x00
            &Intel8080::op_nop,
            // 0x01
            &Intel8080::op_lxi,
            // 0x02:
            &Intel8080::op_stax,
...
```

but how to execute it in code (in old C++ compiler)?

Comment: I added ```#include <functional>``` but the error is the same: 
error: 'invoke' is not a member of 'std'
         std::invoke(op_codes[op_code], this);
              ^~~~~~

Comment: @wally See the [working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jq8vqY16z) given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77879970/12002570).

Comment: The problem with the braced list is that you can mess up the comments, and have wrong opcodes at wrong indices. But that syntax will work in the member init list: `Intel8080() : op_codes{...} {}`. `std::array` additionally allows you to do `op_codes = {...}` in the constructor body.

Comment: What exactly is the question? You have a class (code provided), you initialize the array (code provided), and you use the array (code provided). Try posing your question in your text instead of hoping people guess it from reading the code.

Comment: I see two questions posed in the code, how to define an array and how to use pointers to member functions. These are distinct topics, so should be separate questions. (I'm willing to grant that definition and initialization are linked subjects.) For the former (how to define an array), I recommend using a simpler type for your question. For the latter (how to use your pointers), see [How can I create a pointer to a member function and call it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1485983). Most importantly, one question per question is the goal.

Comment: "functins need access to class fields, I cannot define theme as static" Not the functions, but the array of pointer-to-functions. You are already passing a `CPU *` to them, the `this` in `std::invoke(op_codes[op_code], this);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `std::invoke`(with C++17) to make a call using member function pointer. Additionally, it would be better to initialize the array in the *member initilizer list* instead of assigning to it in the constructor body.

```
//use member initializer list
Cpu::Cpu(): op_codes(new OpCode[256]{&Cpu::op_nop, &Cpu::op_lxi, &Cpu::op_stax})
{                      
     //this is assignment           
     op_codes = new OpCode[256]{&Cpu::op_nop, &Cpu::op_lxi, &Cpu::op_stax};
}
void Cpu::SingleStep()
{
    uint8_t op_code = 0x00;
    
    //call using std::invoke
    std::invoke(op_codes[op_code], this);

    //old style call without std::invoke
    (this->*op_codes[op_code])();
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5PG4sb4YM)

---

> can I initialize the array in the ctor body?

We can do assignment inside the ctor body.

```
Cpu::Cpu()
{                      
     //this is assignment           
     op_codes = new OpCode[256]{&Cpu::op_nop, &Cpu::op_lxi, &Cpu::op_stax};
}
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5PG4sb4YM)

Comment: looks promising, let me test it...

Comment: can I initialize the array in the ctor body? It is 256 itemsm quite a lot

```
op_codes = { &Intel8080::op_nop, &Intel8080::op_lxi, ,... }
```

Comment: @wally Yes you can. See my updated answer [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5PG4sb4YM). Note that it is called assignment not initialization inside the constructor.

Comment: @wally Inside the ctor body you can do this like `Cpu::Cpu()
{                      
        
     op_codes = new OpCode[256]{&Cpu::op_nop, &Cpu::op_lxi, &Cpu::op_stax};
}`

Comment: Thank you guys. You are all AWESOME!!!! Thank you so much for the demo and your effort @user12002570

Comment: @wally I wouldn't use "new" (though you did ask for it), but if you are then store the pointer in a "std::unique_ptr" (longer story and read up on "std::make_unique()" as well). I'd use a "std::array" instead though or old-style C array. With a "std::array" for instance (though you did post similar earlier), `#include <array>` and then `std::array<OpCode, 256> op_codes;` and `Cpu::Cpu() noexcept : op_codes{&Cpu::op_nop, &Cpu::op_lxi, ... }{}`